# Fibonacci program lengths

Tags: code-golf, quine, fibonacci, code-generation

Write a program with length n that outputs another program whose length is the next Fibonacci number after n. The new program must do the same thing - output another program whose length is the next Fibonacci number, etc.
n itself (the original program's length) does not have to be a Fibonacci number, although it would be nice if it is.

Shortest code wins.

No external resources, ASCII only, free compiler/interpreter required.
If your output ends in a newline, it is also counted.

Comment: Does this need to continue on forever? (`int` or `BigInteger`)

Comment: @Quincunx it's ok if it stops working at int's limit or compiler/interpreter's limit, whichever comes first. I expect it to get to 10000+ though.

Comment: Are there restrictions on use of whitespace or comments or arbitrarily long variable/function/class names in either the original or subsequently produced programs?

Comment: Can the program read its own source code, or are you looking for a true quasi-quine?

Comment: @JonathanPullano no restrictions, they just need to be valid programs

Comment: @histocrat I think reading own source is ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## CJam, <strike>26</strike> 23

I just had a try with your language.

```
7{9\@5mq)2/*')*\"_~"}_~
```

9 is `(22*0.618 + 0.5 - 1)/1.618 + 1`.

It computes its own length`*1.618` instead of repeatedly adding the two numbers. In the first version, it will fill the output before `{` like `1)))))))))`, which counts those characters themselves. Say the result `n`. The total length is `n+22`, and the new length before `{` should be `(n+22)*1.618-22`, rounded. Decrease it by one to count the number of `)`'s. Then it will be approximately equal to `(n+8)*1.618`.

Older version:

```
-3{1\@5mq)2/*E+')*\"_~"}_~
```

The number 14 is `24*0.618 + 0.5 - 1`.

Comment: Very impressive!

Comment: I think we have a new winner :)

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 160 bytes

```python
s='s=%s;c=s;l=len(s%%c)+4;a,b=1,1\nwhile b<l:a,b=b,a+b\nc+="1"*(b-l-1);print s%%`c`;a=1'
c=s
l=len(s%c)+4
a,b=1,1
while b<l:a,b=b,a+b
c+="1"*(b-l-1)
print s%`c`
```

This is a true quasi-quine; it doesn't read its own source, but it generates it. First output (has trailing newline):

```python
s='s=%s;c=s;l=len(s%%c)+4;a,b=1,1\nwhile b<l:a,b=b,a+b\nc+="1"*(b-l-1);print s%%`c`;a=111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111';c=s;l=len(s%c)+4;a,b=1,1
while b<l:a,b=b,a+b
c+="1"*(b-l-1);print s%`c`;a=1
```

Second:

```python
s='s=%s;c=s;l=len(s%%c)+4;a,b=1,1\nwhile b<l:a,b=b,a+b\nc+="1"*(b-l-1);print s%%`c`;a=1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111';c=s;l=len(s%c)+4;a,b=1,1
while b<l:a,b=b,a+b
c+="1"*(b-l-1);print s%`c`;a=111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

<sub>Edit: Oops. Forgot to change the string when I changed from `;`s to `1`s, so the second output was outputting extra semicolons (which Python doesn't support). Fixed</sub>

Comment: I'm afraid it stops working after about 3 iterations...

Comment: @aditsu What? Python has a limit on the size of an integer?! (or is it that the count isn't a fibonacci / skips / something else?) Oh wait. Duh. I forgot to change the string XD

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>41</s> 31 bytes

```
{1$+S@]_1=4+1$`,-S*"2$~"}21D2$~
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### Output

```
$ cjam <(echo '{1$+S@]_1=4+1$`,-S*"2$~"}21D2$~'); echo
{1$+S@]_1=4+1$`,-S*"2$~"}34 21 2$~
$ cjam <(echo '{1$+S@]_1=4+1$`,-S*"2$~"}21D2$~') | wc -c
34
$ cjam <(cjam <(echo '{1$+S@]_1=4+1$`,-S*"2$~"}21D2$~')); echo
{1$+S@]_1=4+1$`,-S*"2$~"}55 34                      2$~
$ cjam <(cjam <(echo '{1$+S@]_1=4+1$`,-S*"2$~"}21D2$~')) | wc -c
55
$ cjam (cjam <(cjam <(echo '{1$+S@]_1=4+1$`,-S*"2$~"}21D2$~'))); echo
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `cjam'
$ cjam <(cjam <(cjam <(echo '{1$+S@]_1=4+1$`,-S*"2$~"}21D2$~'))); echo
{1$+S@]_1=4+1$`,-S*"2$~"}89 55                                                        2$~
$ cjam <(cjam <(cjam <(echo '{1$+S@]_1=4+1$`,-S*"2$~"}21D2$~'))) | wc -c
89
```

#### How it works

```
{       "                                                   {…} 21 13                     ";
  1$+   " Duplicate the higher number and add.              {…} 21 34                     ";
  S@    " Push a space and rotate the lower number on top.  {…} 34 ' ' 21                 ";
  ]     " Wrap the stack into an array.                     [ {…} 34 ' ' 21 ]             ";
  _1=   " Push the second element of the array.             [ {…} 34 ' ' 21 ] 34          ";
  4+    " Add 4 to it.                                      [ {…} 34 ' ' 21 ] 38          ";
  1$`,  " Push the length of the stringified array.         [ {…} 34 ' ' 21 ] 38 37       ";
  -S*   " Subtract and push that many spaces.               [ {…} 34 ' ' 21 ] ' '         ";
  "2$~" " Push the string '2$~'.                            [ {…} 34 ' ' 21 ] ' ' '2$~'   ";
}       "                                                   {…}                           ";

21D     " Push 21 and 13.                                   {…} 21 13                     ";
2$~     " Copy the code block an evaluate.                  [ {…} 34 ' ' 21 ] ' ' '2$~'   ";
```

Comment: Nice, confirmed up to 1 million :) I think it's 37 instead of 39 though in the explanation.

Comment: @aditsu: Didn't notice you edited your comment until right now. It should be 37 indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

## Python - 89

```py
g="%(s,b,a+b);print o.ljust(b-1)";s,a,b="s,a,b=%r,%i,%i;o=s%"+g,89,144;exec("o=s"+g)#####
```

My perfect character count is *gone*. ;_; Thanks to TheRare for pointing out the newline thing and Quincunx for suggesting I use Python 2, shaving off 2 chars.

**EDIT**: Now just uses more `#`s instead of `1`s; 12 chars shorter.

**EDIT 2**: 94 chars! Eliminated some repetition. >:3

**EDIT 3**: Shorter repr alternative for Python 2.

**EDIT 4**: Output is a character shorter now.

**EDIT 5**: The use of `%r` to shorten it was taken from an answer on another question by @primo.

**EDIT 6**: Shorter. :D

Here's a Python 3 version:

```py
g="%(s,b,a+b);print(o.ljust(b-1))";s,a,b="s,a,b=%r,%i,%i;o=s%"+g,89,144;exec("o=s"+g)####
```

This answer is similar to the one by @Quincunx.

Comment: `print` always adds a newline, unless you specify `end=''` argument.

Comment: Why not use Python 2?: ``s,a,b="s,a,b=%s,%i,%i;o=s%%(`s`,b,a+b)+'#';print o+(b-len(o)-1)*'1'",89,144;o=s%(`s`,b,a+b)+'#';print o+(b-len(o)-1)*'1'``

Comment: @Quincunx I shall! Thanks :D

Comment: Your 90-char program doesn't work with python 3, and has a 145-char output (not a Fibonacci number)

Comment: @aditsu Fixed. :3

Comment: Nice use of `%r` ;)

Comment: @primo I totally copied from you, lol. Lemme edit :3

Comment: With a program length of 84, I expect a first output of 89 characters.

Comment: @aditsu Imma just pad it with hashes. Not even worth it.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 94

```
(function q(w,e){return ('('+q+')('+e+','+(s=w+e)+')'+Array(s).join('/')).substr(0,s)})(55,89)
```

Based on a well-known [JavaScript Quine](http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/self_javas.txt), this returns almost the same function, only followed by amount of slashes, such that it sums up to 144 which is the next Fibonacci number after N. And so on...

N is not a Fibonacci number, but it was only "nice to have".

Comment: It doesn't seem to work correctly when it passes 1000

Comment: 1000 what? Iterations?

Comment: No, program length

Comment: Hmm... I was testing it in Chrome's Console, using `p = (my answer)` and then `p = eval(p)` a couple of times, and got until **196418**... after that processing time was > 1sec so I quit testing :P But I guess it can continue even more.

Comment: You don't understand.. I didn't say it stops working or it's too slow. I said it doesn't work correctly. Don't just do `p=eval(p)`, also check `p.length`. After it gets to 987, I get length 1598, not a Fibonacci number.

Comment: Now I get it. You're right - I have a bug in there... I will fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15180/discussion-between-jacob-and-aditsu).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 65 bytes

```python
a,b=55,89;exec(s:="print((f'a,b={b,a+b};exec(s:=%r)#'%s*b)[:b])")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCoMwEETv@YolRUza5CBFsCl@iXhINGkDEiXxUBG/3Rot9rQ7O8ubGabx3bt7Mfi16VtdYoxXyVSZ56x4PPVHNySIEg/eupEQk0ZvVkze1HK6iaeXNAlXRSuhaorpulGqTPCsRqjVBlobhk5OJFCBAA6WSTnnBOZOu@2@AN1kSk87xPXV9Up2EIttKg4oISBkeg8WrAMv3UuTfMfubeIPm4@6WPxylz@Wrl8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 63 bytes

```
(f(a,b)=print1(s=Str("(f="f")("b","a+b");")10^(b-#s-1)))(55,89)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgFATQu0ybGVLIhVCEp2gf@BeGmxDt/vZey736p83JwuxMqfX6foEjXV8nWBIKRBgc8mrQCYXtpvll@CCJMbr90Jw/)

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica

```
({0};
 With[{n = Ceiling[ InverseFunction[Fibonacci]@LeafCount@#0 ], l = Length[#0[[1, 1]]]},
    #0 /. {0..} -> ConstantArray[0, Fibonacci[n+1] - LeafCount[#0] + l]
 ]) &
```

This is a very straightforward implementation (i.e. no obfuscation here).  It is an anonymous function that returns itself with a bit of padding to achieve the correct length.  Mathematica is homoiconic: code and data are both represented as Mathematica expressions, which makes it realtively easy to modify/generate code on the fly.  This also means that character counts are not a natural measure of code length.  Epxression size (["leaf count"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html)) is.  This version is based on leaf counts as code length measure.

If we assign this anonymous function to a variable `f` (so I can show what happens in a readable manner), and keep calling it 1, 2, 3, ... times, each time measuring the length of the return value, this is what we get:

```
In[]:= f // LeafCount
Out[]= 42

In[]:= f[] // LeafCount
Out[]= 89

In[]:= f[][] // LeafCount
Out[]= 144

In[]:= f[][][] // LeafCount
Out[]= 233
```

Regarding the free interpreter requirement: Mathematica is free for the Raspberry Pi.  Otherwise this code should be straightforward to port to [Mathics (open source)](http://www.mathics.net/).  The only thing missing from Mathics is `InverseFunction`, which can be replaced as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5162856/695132) (but I'm lazy :).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know Mathematica was free for the Pi, I should check it out. However, the program is supposed to print characters to the standard output, and that's what should be counted.

Comment: @aditsu Actually I did this more for fun than to compete in the challenge, and using `LeafCount` seemed much more interesting than using character counts (which would imply boring code-manipulation as string-manipulation). :-) I'm not going to change it to use character counts, but I can delete it without any bad feelings if you wish.

Comment: Oh, I see. Just leave it then, no need to delete.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 78 bytes

```python
p,c=55,89;exec(s:="print((a:=f'p,c={c},{p+c};exec(s:=%r)'%s)+'#'*(c-len(a)))")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v0An2dbUVMfC0jq1IjVZo9jKVqmgKDOvREMj0co2TR0kXZ1cq1NdoJ1cC1eiWqSprlqsqa2urK6lkaybk5qnkaipqamk@f8/AA)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 79 bytes

```python
p,c,s=55,89,"a='p,c,s=%d,%d,%r;exec s'%(c,p+c,s);print a+'#'*(c-len(a))";exec s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v0AnWafY1tRUx8JSRynRVh3CV03RAaEi69SK1GSFYnVVjWSdAm2gjKZ1QVFmXolCora6srqWRrJuTmqeRqKmphJU5f//AA)