# Fibonacci reversed!

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, fibonacci

### Introduction

We all know and love our Fibonacci sequence and have seen a myriad of challenge on it here already. However, we're still lacking a very simple case which this answer is going to provide: Reversed fibonacci! **So given `F_n` your job is to find `n`.**

### Specification

#### Input

Your input will be a non-negative integer, which is guaranteed to be part of the fibonacci sequence.

#### Output

The output must be a non-negative integer as well.

#### What to do?

The introduction already said: Given a fibonacci number, output its index. Fiboancci number hereby is defined as `F(0)=0, F(1)=1, F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)` and you're given `F(n)` and must return `n`.

#### Potential Corner Cases

0 is a valid in- and output.
If given "1" as input you may either output "1" or "2", as you prefer.
You may always assume that your input actually is a fibonacci number.
You may assume that the input is representable as a 32-bit signed integer.

#### Who wins?

This is code-golf so the shortest answer in bytes wins!
Standard rules apply of course.

### Test-cases

```
0 -> 0
2 -> 3
3 -> 4
5 -> 5
8 -> 6
13 -> 7
1836311903 -> 46
```

Comment: Slight nit-pick: shouldn't this be considered *inverse* fibonacci https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function

Comment: So, iccanobiF?!

Comment: @Michael this is not inverse Fibonacci, because there's no inverse to Fibonacci function because it is _not_ injective (because the "1" appears twice). The reverse originally came from the idea of "reverse table look-ups" which is what I expected people to do here (e.g. I expected them to do it to solve the problem).

Comment: The function here could be considered a [right inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses) of the "Fibonacci function" from the non-negative integers to the set of Fibonacci numbers. The existence of a right inverse does not imply injectivity.

Comment: @MatthewRoh [Already Taken](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/52089/34718). I already did that. :P

Comment: @SEJPM: I kinda did expect a task like "write a program that spells out the fibonacci sequence backwards", though.

Comment: @SEJPM: It is if you limit its domain so that `1` appears only once. Sort of like how `arcsin(x)` is considered to be the inverse of `sin(x)`, even though `sin(x)` is not injective (or even surjective) in and of itself. It's all about that context!

Answer (score 62):

### Actually, 1 byte

```
f
```

Yes, there's a builtin for this, [since November 16, 2015](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/commit/239b5cc6b71b22e96e5ced7ac3ba34ee499ae3e3).

[Try it online](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=Zg&input=OA)

---

For fun, without the builtin, it's 9 bytes:

```
╗1`F╜=`╓i
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4pWXMWBG4pWcPWDilZNp&input=OA)

Explanation:

```
╗1`F╜=`╓i
╗          push input to register 0
 1`F╜=`╓   push list containing first value x (starting with x = 0) where:
   F         fib(x)
    ╜=       is equal to the input
        i  flatten the list
```

Comment: I have one thought and one thought only when I see this: ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I don't really understand why you would "waste" a symbol for such a ridiculously specific purpose

Comment: @Fatalize The Fibonacci and inverse Fibonacci functions were among the first that I added. Even now, there are 39 completely unused single-byte commands (and who knows how many overloads that could be utilized). The 256 symbols, combined with the fact that there are 5 types in Actually (Integer, Real, String, Iterable, Function), means there are up to 1280 possible unary functions, and 6400 possible binary functions. There's a *lot* of room for seemingly-useless commands.

Comment: @Mego Are you just trying to compete with Mathematica for the most builtins?

Comment: Actually, it's just a byte... lol, love this language name.

Comment: Now we have to invent a language where an empty file means inverse Fibonacci to triumph this.

Answer (score 44):

## Mathematica, 25 bytes

```
InverseFunction@Fibonacci
```

Function. Pretty self-explanatory if you ask me.

Answer (score 32):

## Python, <s>36</s> <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```python
lambda n:len(str(66*n**6))//1.24
```

#### Previous versions:

```python
f=lambda n:len(str(66*n**6))//1.24
f=lambda n:(n*n*7).bit_length()//1.4
```

### Explanation

The core idea is to invert the formula

```python
fibonacci(n) ~ ( (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2)**n / sqrt(5)
```

which tells us that

```python
log fibonacci(n) ~ n log((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2) - log(sqrt(5))
```

to get

```python
f(n) ~ (log(n) + log(sqrt(5))) / log((1 + sqrt(5))/2)
```

The golfing optimizations are:

- Use `len(str(n))` to compute log base 10 without importing `log` (old version used `.bit_length()` to compute log base 2)
- Raise `n` to a power, so that the approximation of the logarithm can distinguish between successive Fibonacci numbers
- Multiplying by a constant scales up the values to get them in the correct range

Then the divisor was truncated to as little precision as I could manage and the multiplier chosen to give the correct results for all 32-bit fibonacci numbers.

Comment: it should be 32 bytes, because `f=` is not counted.

Comment: As the comment above already said, [anonymous functions/unnamed lambdas are allowed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1503/12012). Also, if you restrict your answer to Python 2 and require a *long* argument, ``lambda n:~-len(`66*n**6`)//1.24`` should work.

Answer (score 19):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

Code:

```
ÅFg
```

Explanation:

```
ÅF   # Generate all Fibonacci numbers <= input.
  g  # Get the length of this list.
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w4VGZw&input=MTgzNjMxMTkwMw).

Answer (score 16):

## Julia, <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 18 bytes

```julia
!n=log(3n+.7)÷.48
```

This uses the inverse of [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding), with just enough precision for  32-bit integers; it actually works up to **F(153) = 42,230,279,526,998,466,217,810,220,532,898 > 2<sup>105</sup>**.

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IW49bG9nKDNuKy43KcO3LjQ4Cgpmb3IgbiBpbiAoMCwgMSwgMiwgMywgNSwgOCwgMTMsIDE4MzYzMTE5MDMsIDQyMjMwMjc5NTI2OTk4NDY2MjE3ODEwMjIwNTMyODk4KQogICAgQHByaW50ZigiJTMydSAtPiAlM3VcbiIsIG4sICFuKQplbmQ&input=)

#### How it works

Binet's formula states the following.

[image: Binet's formula]

Restricting **F** to the set of Fibonacci, the map **n → F<sub>n</sub>** has a [right inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses) **F → n<sub>F</sub>**.

We have that

[image: right inverse of Binet's formula]

and all that is left to do is dealing with the edge case **0**.

Since the input is restricted to 32-bit integers, we can use short decimal literals instead of the constants in the formula.

- **log φ = 0.481211825059603447… ≈ 0.48**

  Unfortunately, **0.5** isn't precise enough.
- **√5 = 2.2360679774997896964… ≈ 3**

  That might seem like an awful approximation at first glance, but we're taking logarithms and since **log 3 - log √5 = 0.29389333245105…**, the result before rounding will be off by a small constant factor.
- **0.5 ≈ 0.7**

  Because of the excess from the previous approximation, we could actually omit this term altogether and still get correct results for **F > 0**. However, if **F = 0**, the logarithm will be undefined. **0.7** turned out to be the shortest value that extends our formula to **F = 0**.

Answer (score 9):

## Jelly, <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
5½×lØp+.Ḟ»0
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=NcK9w5dsw5hwKy7huJ7CuzA&input=&args=OA)

This is my first ever Jelly answer! This uses the algorithm [from the MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85573/31716). Thanks to Dennis for shaving off 3 bytes!

Explanation:

```
   lØp      # Log Base phi
5½          # Of the square root of 5
  ×         # Times the input
      +     # Plus
       .    # 0.5
        Ḟ   # Floored
```

This gets the right answer, now we just need to handle the special case of '0'. With '0' as an arg, we get `-infinity`, so we return

```
»      # The maximum of 
 0     # Zero
       # And the previous calculated value.
```

Comment: +1 because the comments on the explanation are the end of a limerick.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript, <s>54</s> <s>50</s> <s>69</s> <s>50</s> 42 bytes

```
b=>(j=>{for(i=c=0;b-i;c++)i=j+(j=i)})(1)|c
```

Surely it isn't going to win, just for fun :)

<s>Ok, checking for zero consumes 19 bytes. WTF?</s> Stupid-me.

---

Demo! To see the last test case, you have to scroll the console a bit.

```js
a=b=>(j=>{for(i=c=0;b-i;c++)i=j+(j=i)})(1)|c;
console.log('0: '+a(0));
console.log('2: '+a(2));
console.log('3: '+a(3));
console.log('5: '+a(5));
console.log('8: '+a(8));
console.log('13: '+a(13));
console.log('1836311903: '+a(1836311903));
```

Thanks @edc for shortening by 8 bytes.

Comment: simple `b=>{for(j=1,i=c=0;b-i;c++)i=j+(j=i);return c}` 45, golfed `b=>(j=>{for(i=c=0;b-i;c++)i=j+(j=i)})(1)|c` 42.

Comment: @edc Wow, that's clever, thanks <3

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org)  <s>33 30</s>  27 bytes

```perl6
{first *==$_,:k,(0,1,*+*...*>$_)}
{first *==$_,:k,(0,1,*+*...*)}
{first $_,:k,(0,1,*+*...*)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#ZZDPboJAEMbvPMUcjIKuZGeBBTSanvoEvRnT4LpUggLKYjXGx@7Z7q6tbdPbb/58M/NN10o4cl9MnU7Ti2zV1HF2Z@jnxWpcVGt5ghncLnlxaBX0XsmkJC4lSIajoe/7Q@96081PSuta3eg6ABRmc6BEEzMUGAoMhYYiQ5GhxBA3hLYcW0wCHiCm9K64lxmjFDkNMUKGSczjwGpTOxrTOKQsDhmmCU8YC5DHtmrXBVHIWJiECcYp45hiRGN7AlJ9oqe9NtusgtGXgxGgTuX14dvSeK5NgwuTUp7dXlE1nfIITI7ZtpNuT54aKZRce@DBRW8Tu2Zcl/B43Y@iv5D745LAQ0LAfyta5Vwd55/qz4MX@lK6/DXCxAQG7/WhbKFrQNU2pTYgt3InKwV1Ds/Fqq4yIQpo5b6TlZCD20dVj0UmNvIT)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
# lambda with implicit ｢$_｣ parameter
{
  first           # find the first element
    $_,           # where something is equal to the block's argument
    :k,           # return the key rather than the value

    # of the Fibonacci sequence
    ( 0, 1, * + * ... * )
    # ^--^ first two values
    #       ^---^ lambda used to generate the next in the series
    #             ^-^ generate until
    #                 ^ Whatever
}
```

#### Test:

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;
use Test;

# using the safer version that stops generating
# values bigger than the input
my &fib-index = {first $_,:k,(0,1,*+*...*>$_)}

my @tests = (
  0 => 0,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 4,
  5 => 5,
  8 => 6,
  13 => 7,
  1836311903 => 46,
  1836311904 => Nil, # this is why the safe version is used here
  12200160415121876738 => 93,
  19740274219868223167 => 94,
  354224848179261915075 => 100,
);

plan +@tests + 1;

for @tests -> $_ ( :key($input), :value($expected) ) {
  cmp-ok fib-index($input), &[eqv], $expected, .gist
}

cmp-ok fib-index((0,1,*+*...*)[1000]), &[eqv], 1000, 'works up to 1000th element of Fibonacci sequence'
```

```perl6
1..13
ok 1 - 0 => 0
ok 2 - 2 => 3
ok 3 - 3 => 4
ok 4 - 5 => 5
ok 5 - 8 => 6
ok 6 - 13 => 7
ok 7 - 1836311903 => 46
ok 8 - 1836311904 => Nil
ok 9 - 12200160415121876738 => 93
ok 10 - 19740274219868223167 => 94
ok 11 - 354224848179261915075 => 100
ok 12 - works up to 1000th element of Fibonacci sequence
```

Comment: You can replace `first *==$_` with just `first $_`, because a number is a valid smart-matcher.

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZDBboJAEIbvPMUciIIC2VlgFzSanvoEvZnGKI4tEQFlsRrjs9NdbG2bXjbfzsw/88/UdCxE1zYEJxFkU8vQCzVqaln7Cwy2@drPyw2dYQbd1XGYh95oPAqCYOTqx166Pt46XfmktKjRVY4FwGA2B@Zp4oZCQ6GhyFBsKDaUGBKGsE/LHpNQhIgpuyvuac4ZQ8EijJFjIoUMe23at8ZURozLiGOaiITzEIXss/24MI44j5IoQZlygSnGTPYWkGmLrl60LlYljL82GAPq0LY6fq/kz8FeggOTHV0cOy/rVrkeTE6roiXHpnNNmaKNCy5c9bRsX/vVDh53@1EMFnQ4vXrwkHgQvOWNsm6W9U/159AL7ZS9/mph/h4MP6rjroG2BlX1IfUOVNCeSgXVFp7zdVWusiyHhg4tlRkNu08) by using the `...` operator instead of `first`

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
1+Ð¡0
¢i
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MSvDkMKhMArComk&input=&args=MTM) Note that this approach is too inefficient for the last test case.

#### How it works

```
¢i     Main link. Argument: n

¢      Call the helper link niladically (i.e., without arguments).
       This yields the sequence of the first n positive Fibonacci numbers, i.e.,
       [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...].
 i     Find the first index of n (1-based, 0 if not found).


1+Ð¡0  Helper link. No arguments.

1      Set the left argument to 1.
    0  Yield 0.
 +Ð¡   Add both arguments, replacing the left argument with the sum and the right
       argument with the previous value of the left argument.
       Yield the array of all intermediate values of the left argument.
```

Answer (score 6):

### Pyke, 5 bytes

```
.f.bq
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.f.bq&input=8&warnings=0)

```
.f    - first number where
  .b  -  fib(n)
    q - ^ == input
```

Answer (score 6):

### Python, 29 bytes

```python
g=lambda n:n>.7and-~g(n/1.61)
```

Recursively divides the input by the golden-ratio approximation 1.61 until it's below 0.7, and outputs the number of divisions.

For 0, the code outputs `False`, [which equals 0 in Python](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9064/20260). This can be avoided for 2 bytes

```python
g=lambda n:n//.7and 1+g(n/1.61)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
t?5X^*17L&YlYo
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dD81WF4qMTdMJllsWW8&input=MTgzNjMxMTkwMw)

This uses [an inverse of Binet's formula](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39124/fibonacci-sequence-inversion), and so it's very fast.

Let *F* denote the *n*-th Fibonacci number, and *φ* the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). Then

[image]

The code uses this formula with two modifications:

- Instead of adding 1/2 and then rounding down, the code simply rounds towards the nearest integer, which takes up fewer bytes.
- Input *F*=0 needs to be treated as a special case.

#### How it's done

```
t         % Take input F implicitly. Make a copy
?         % If (copy of) F is positive
  5X^     %   Push sqrt(5)
  *       %   Multiply by F
  17L     %   Push phi (predefined literal)
  &Yl     %   Two-input logarithm: first input is argument, second is base
  Yo      %   Round towards nearest integer
          % Else the input, which is 0, is left on the stack
          % End if implicitly
          % Display implicitly
```

Comment: Alternate approach: `O1G:"yy+]vGmfq`

Comment: 11 bytes: [`t?17L&YlXkQ`](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8Te0NxHLTInIjvw/39DC2MzY0NDSwNjAA)

Comment: @jimmy23013 Nice approach! You should definiely post that as a separate answer

Comment: I don't think it is worth another answer, as it is just a way to remove the `5X^*`. ([I have done this before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32013/25180).) And I don't know MATL enough to possibly keep improving it.

Answer (score 4):

### Sage, 49 bytes

```py
lambda x,s=sqrt(5):x and int(log(x*s,(1+s)/2)+.5)
```

Thanks to TuukkaX for the suggestion about saving `sqrt(5)` as `s` to shave off a few bytes.

[Try it online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs81JzE1KSVSo0Cm2LS4sKtEw1bSqUEjMS1HIzCvRyMlP16jQKtbRMNQu1tQ30tTWM9Xk5eLlKigCyiqkaaRlJuXnJSYnZ2oYGhhoagIAwWAXHw==&lang=sage).

This approach using an inverse of Binet's formula offers several improvements over the previous approach: it's faster (constant-time versus quadratic time), it actually works for larger inputs, and it's shorter!

Python users may wonder why I'm using `sqrt(5)` instead of the shorter `5**.5` - it's because `5**.5` is computed with C's `pow` function, and loses precision due to floating point issues. Many mathematical functions (including `sqrt` and `log`) are overloaded in Sage to return an exact, symbolic value, which don't lose precision.

Comment: I don't know Sage at all but could you save bytes by holding the `sqrt(5)` in a variable and use it twice, instead of typing `sqrt(5)` twice?

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>39</s> 33 bytes

```
f=(n,j=0,k=1)=>n>j?f(n,k,j+k)+1:0
```

Even with ES7, the inverse Binet formula takes 47 bytes:

```
x=>Math.log(x*5**.5)/Math.log(.5+1.25**.5)+.5|0
x=>Math.log(x*5**.5)/Math.log((1+5**.5)/2)+.5|0
x=>Math.log(x*(p=5**.5))/Math.log((1+p)/2)+.5|0
```

Comment: Just distribute the `log` and precompute all constants...

Comment: IMHO, if you call recursively the lambda by name, `f(n,k,j+k)`, you should include the assignment `f=` and count it as **+2 bytes**. The rule for unnamed lambdas should not apply here.

Comment: @charlie Sorry, I always forgot about that. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript, 22 bytes

```
n=>Math.log(n)/.48+2|0
```

Comment: I didn't think this would work when I saw it, but apparently `-Infinity|0` is `0` in JavaScript. Go figure.

Comment: @Dennis: In JS, bitwise operators take only last 32 bits and `-Infinity = FFF00000 00000000`. I was glad to find out, it spares 3 bytes for not having to prepend an explicit zero test like `n&&`. Apart from that, the main purpose of `|0` is a substitute for `Math.trunc()` (like `÷` in Julia).

Answer (score 4):

## Regex (.NET), <s>23</s> 19 bytes

```
(\2?(\1)|x$|^x|\b)*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BboMwFET3nOILfQk7FBRadRPLaqSue4KQSsb5CZYAIxsESsi2B@gRexHqtovOZkYzize9ncj5mppmRScPji40H3e7jia2T1ZWPr6wsuDLjMv7vJQV36zJ/iF@tW1vGjrFXOBVbkV0to4hQxUyVrIQaOSWC0CTNQRPzz8pTTncIgjCFiSgy9/UoGvyLJmTDSoufkdzZnjlt8mZgbLa@uEeCIWA/wKyzoZ/jekIYlTw9fEJgd3mF2fH3h@KY65VP4yOfK7t2A08/sNqiSo8URKrYFUqUYvovn4D)

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number. Returns its output as the capture count of group `\1`.

This is based on [Martin Ender's .NET regex for matching Fibonacci numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126373/am-i-a-fibonacci-number/126405#126405). The .NET feature of balanced groups is used to count the number of iterations taken by the loop.

- That regex is first initially translated to use `x` as its unary numeral, yielding `^$|^(^x|(?>\2?)(\1))*x$`.
- Then the `x$` at the end is moved inside as the extra alternative `|x$`, incrementing the loop count by \$1\$ for all \$n>0\$. This also allows us to remove the `^$|` at the beginning, because `^(^x|(?>\2?)(\1)|x$)*$` will now match \$n=0\$ on its own. (It will also now match numbers that are \$0\$ or \$1\$ less than a Fibonacci number, but we don't care because as specified by the challenge, all inputs will be Fibonacci numbers.)
- Then the extra alternative `|\b` is added to increment the loop count again for all \$n>0\$; `\b` cannot match on an input of \$n=0\$ because there is no word character (`[0-9A-Za-z_]`) to form a boundary with the absense of a word character, but it will always match at the end of a string of one or more `x`s. The match is zero-width, so the loop will then be terminated.
- Then we remove the `^` and `$` anchors sandwiching the regex, because we don't need to return a non-match for non-Fibonacci numbers.
- Then an optimization for speed, moving the `^x` alternative as far to the end as possible, because it only has to match once, and would add a failed match to every subsequent iteration if ordered as the first alternative.
- The `\2?` can lose the `(?>`...`)` atomic group around it, because we don't need to determine if a number is Fibonacci or not. Due to the lack of any assertions following the loop, it will simply keep the first match it finds at each iteration, not having any reason to backtrack.

**27 byte** version that matches iff the input is a Fibonacci number:

```
^((?>\2?)(\1)\B|x$|^x|\b)*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BboMwEEWvYlkjYYcaQboLchO1654AiESJEyw5tmUbgQJse4AesRehpFHV5Zv5evPHml443wqlFnC8cOIihmq306Inh2g5ErJ/Kbd7SsqMlq/TANNxmMoPuoElOjzhN3O1UokTpjnceJqfjRN10xJQSGoEUtsu0BFqDop5q2TADOfyTKBOGtPpwFRA23sg5lAXaTWvAgKaF1KH6neSg2ZK/HF25zim491x5eCS9zo0rfAkGqINaPrY3OjYOxkEa40P89osy/8ZMW3W95TUAmHQ6PvzC8FqSy7OdNavN5KmtqFzwj9KUjzP85Ky7DlNfwA)

The `\B` prevents numbers \$1\$ less than a Fibonacci number from being matched; in unary, `\B` matches at every place except the beginning and end in a non-zero number (and matches "everywhere" in an input of zero).

## Regex  (PCRE1 / PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.34 or earlier</sup></sub>), 20 bytes

```
^(\2?(\1)|x$|^x)+|^x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNtb9owEP7Or7hma4mJW0HRpongVlvXaR9YOyEqbQIaGeOEqMGJnGTQt6/7AfuJ@yFjlzihdC8RJOfz3XN3z2OLJDkMhNi8CJWI8rmEfiK0PFqcNMSCa/CS8RQYDK13q9XNrJt/vb39Mlq8Xi3szbU9OT61Jx3ysH75cL0mDr425M84i0IrYV7idNzGU400m4dxUWTXpUMVPPeFMXolX/4dd9IIVQYJmpkntY61LWKVZlA23VrKNOWBJPdYp9cTGAD9PlTewiz9Us0jF7TMcq2g4z42cpWGgZJziGIVmBdX6Upqt6y2vPUEj6I4z@yCo3rhzaJY3EBLELg34Y6zhW0jbJnLQ2VjQAPwScY4RCSVnZDDzpS1XTANmdEgEcyyT3uWi5bDEvOxiH16hv89gv4cIbvHXgZxkVzgB2iU2LtAoUryrEjXElpaurDLEZKSZNpka5nmUWbsgk3fT2VGAYfDLoNsYXbib1JksR53p6YUojIwTMTLJIwk0nIkPCxuEwqfz4bn3vvL0dvBAB7M6mr04Q2FA1PZGHWpNjGYoQ/2npak5s8vJfZtHAujKVgFUNmjBo4tlemwP@/BfjpReNh2ME2dCnhXMWz7SUuz7eMJKmbkrE1nrEMFvUMrLOnts@4r5I5xytmMzhwmaOg4tZh113cEkO2CW7s5UU3iwh3ruFD1b@3P4ef3H4Adctwy5wT7qFQrHiNLik4lV2Y15k5n6uLBXeJAdkqhuW4agHTMp2wn2ShY6yHXUthaUri4GgwoYCJHistfJSKFLnGf9W8Q@m04OKjR9pjR7Xw4vBx6F5ef3o7OPpJt1va4iYJTvFXWeaGL9YQro1T@P7wiob6OfpSni39MVE352ChV7xm5tJTYMdnes@oENx43v4Qf8SDdHEYFFb8B) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXvbtpIEP/OU0zcu2QXTA@IWkUYJ8oRpERqSUWJrldCrWW9BqvGtux1SdLmax/gHvEe5Ljx7gJOyOksMLOzM7@dP78deJo255yvX/kiCGMBH/qjQcfrX18MvJvh1dj74@pifAkntVdhzKPCF9BLeSY6rxenNb5gGXjpZAoujKzfV6uvs@Piz/v7T@PF29WCrL@Q284ZuW3TH3e//PhyRxv4WtPndpYN9dT10kbbqRySyyyM5@UpO12YoFaw5eme3WktjCWkKEpPZFmSEZ7EuQQVYX0p8pzNBYXvufS7XY4W0OuBUZei0ovYjxzIhCyyGNrO4x5mueaJL2yYJUkEiRuwKC9h1TEGbtJ583bq1ACfMACiiuXNhcHwjBXROERX@6Z/eT46qVOzaUMePogkINvAf9toKvaUUnVK@ZAEznQSPCkkdGGbKC3Ts5QbqAi6YD1LXjlbFnpZt7FFt/UIoiJf6Ey2Rak91oo4D@ex8CFK4rl@sThficxRBVvee5xFEYZhcjcrbxYl/CvUuQ3fktCHus8kw9qVRSpFcF0g5U6dHu4wqMFuNLadaZnOLFkYEwRQAaYTJEIkYpLSZnvqthydgmYHpNy1yFnXclBquKn@sSg56@P3gKK@QMTjjiexqehbws9RUNBVoDBOC1m6q8SwhVDPxGa9ZJIvPJVLfSdrtEzkRSRt3QLHXLKPV58HShMEucBNzBdTmMvFE4N68k1wiV6mE3jZNucv0zASxJDi44fxiKb8NfcwWEJtg/F5MLr2xoPR@6vh@XhwsVEPPo0Hw4tyfahiMr8mkhbdMfggQwKa2ldvg3obu0rq7l41PFwzKbwgS5ZeyqQUWUwyZPnw5t07A1D1wasrxZ3EIm4k96V9A0v2UDCDLQU3EHaFl/ZLPHsOoI@KwmVYBWm2qVMx8kUq/9coE7zI8jCJXzRUxwZmuDC3Zc/cts3tB5RCRcWee/zGAe4ym7kze9ZwuR02Ghveb5r0QAGZWc4hcnQbH2EAD27b0f0KiPWrD3///Atw1DLc0lcKq2oYXj56UuaojMVKryas0Z46OCmWmAbJbTi6O9IA@YRN3YqzZvfTNqkOV6mJAAyZpT47cqBs6kGdJxlpzF4LDg8N/oFrqDsaXY@84fX783H/cjcDVf8q/NxcOZkVooItcGQ/8dmNTRx8pjQvjMDy8UUkpAD8w8u18vG/yItkF4LsUtu/FNpgu6bVqaI38d5th55OBsfv@h8eRGyer5uRsm@e/As) - PCRE2 v10.33

Takes its input in unary, as the length of a string of `x`s. Returns its output as the number of ways the regex can match. (The rabbit emoji indicates this output method. It can yield outputs bigger than the input, and is really good at multiplying.)

This is a straight port of the .NET version to the  output format. It needs to be anchored, so that the only variation in how a match can happen is how many iterations the loop takes, not where in the string it starts. The `*` is changed to `+` because with the former, looping for 0 iterations would still be a match, and would result in a 1-indexed return value.

Moving the `|\b` alternative to the end as `|^x` is a minor speed optimization, at a zero-byte cost. As an added bonus, we can change this to `|^xx` to return \$1\$ (instead of \$2\$) for an input of \$1\$.

For PCRE1, and PCRE2 before v10.35, the atomic group is not needed even with -output, because those versions automatically atomicize groups that contain a nested backreference (in this case, `\1`).

## Regex  (Perl / PCRE), 23 bytes

```
^(\2?+(\1)|^x)+|^x|^xxx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1NCsIwEIWvEsJQElJqq7ixjkWqW1cuiyEtCoVqS3AR@@PSA3hELxJHYXiPx/fBdGfbLP31wcCmbGjayjQMZilNXO@2x@1mYpfWCjAYh1BiEkKNMeF6jYsldYVgQqJQElYIFQlKyQFy0gR33IGR@JyJbAVWiiwblII8jCf5e9IHQWfr250XN55Cj0nK/puBiTj7vN6MR5CTOBKatN4fdlr7kyjmmRJFIseTk4qCzjnvvw) - Perl v5.28.2 / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY09CsJAEIWvsiyD7LJRE0UQ4xgk2lpZBsMaFALxh0VhNcbSA9jaWGhp7VlsPYmjBob3eHwfzOW2npns-nosdgyMz_JsleiMQd2nid1Bf9zvFWy-MgI0ug5M0XMgRZdw2sVmizpB0A5RmBJWCAkJSskcQtIEt9yClnisi6ADRoogyJWC0HEL-X2yr1TWJl1ueLTkPuzR89lvM9A1zt6nM-M1CEk8ECrieDgaxPF9u5lX28-JiBqBEpEnDxMrFQWdtX96LavsDw) - Perl v5.36+
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNtb9owEP7Or7hmarGJW0HRpomQVl3XaR9YOyEqbQIaBeOEqMGJ7GTQt6/7AfuJ@yFjlzihdC9RCOfz3XN3z2PzND0MOd@8iiSP87mAfsqVOFqcNPjCV@Cl4ym4MLTerVa3s27@9e7uy2jxZrUgmxsyOT61yaRDH2/W1MYPvuv1hv4ZajFopa6X2h2n8VxGZ/MoKersulQkw5e@KEGv8Jd/x500IplBimbmCaUSRXgidQZl362l0NoPBX3AOr0exwDo96HyFmbpF3IeO6BElisJHeepkUsdhVLMIU5kaD6@1CuhnLLa8s7jfhwneUYKmuqFN4sTfgstTuHBhNv2FraNsGWuH0mCAQ3AJx3jELGQJKWHnanbdsA0ZEaDlLsWOe1ZDlq2m5o/i5LTc/ztUfTnCNk99jJIiuQCP0SjxN4FimSaZ0W6EtBSwoFdjpCUNFMmWwmdx5mxCzaDQIuMAQ6HXYbZwuwk3wTPEjXuTk0pRHXBMJEs0ygWSMsR97A4oQw@nw8vvPdXo7PBAB7N6nr04S2DA1PZGHWpNjWYUQBkTwla8xeUEgcEx8JoBlYBVPaowMeWynTYn/dgX08kHrYdTFOnAt5VDNt@1tJsB3iCihl9t81mbodxdo9WVNLbd7uvkTvXZ747YzPb5Syy7VrMuut7Csh2wS1pTmSTOnDvdhyo@rf25/Dz@w/ADn3cMucE@6hUKx4ji0anFCuzGvt2Z@rgwV3iQEQzaK6bBkCP/am7k2wUrPUQa8GJEgwurwcDBpjoI8XlW4nIoEudF/0bhH4bDg5qtD3X6HYxHF4NvcurT2ej8490m7U9brzgFG@VdVHoYj3jiliL/4dXJNTXMYhzvfjHRNWUT41S9Z6RSwmBHdPtPatOcONp84sHsR/qzWFcUPEb) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXvbuJGEP/OU0x8arIL5gpEd4owTpQSpES6IyeOqNcjnLWs12CdsS17fZC0@doH6CP2QUrHuws4IVUtMLOzM7@dP78deJo255xv3vgiCGMBn/qjQcfr314NvLvhzdj79eZqfA1ntTdhzKPCF9BLeSY6bxfnNb5gGXjpZAoujKxfVqvvs9Pit4eHL@PF@9WCbL6R@85Fg9y36R/f1rSBL/ys1xv60tSyoZ66XtpoO5VzcpmF8bw8aK8LE9QKtjw/sDuvhbGEFEXpiSxLMsKTOJeggqwvRZ6zuaDwey79bpejBfR6YNSlqPQi9iMHMiGLLIa283SAWa554gsbZkkSQeIGLMpLWHWMgZt03r2fOjXAJwyAqHp5c2EwPGNFNA7RBb/rX1@OzurUbNqQh48iCcgu8J@3moo9pVSdUj4kgQudBE8KCV3YJUrL9CzlBiqCLlgvklfOloVe1n1s0V09gqjIFzqTXVFqT7UizsN5LHyIkniuXyzOVyJzVMGWDx5nUYRhmNzNyptFCf8OdW7DjyT0oe4zybB2ZZFKEVwXSLlTp8d7DGqwG41dZ1qmM0sWxgQBVIDpBIkQiZiktNmeui1Hp6DZASl3LXLRtRyUGm6qfyxKLvr4PaKoLxDxtONJbCr6lvBzFBR0FSiM00KW7ioxbCHUM7FdL5nkC0/lUt/LGi0TeRFJW7fAMffs883XgdIEQS5wE/PFFOZy8cygnvwQXKKX6QTet@35yzSMBDGk@PxpPKIpf8s9DJZQ22B8HYxuvfFg9PFmeDkeXG3Vgy/jwfCqXB@rmMyviaRF9ww@ypCApvbV26Dexq6SuntQDQ/XTAovyJKllzIpRRaTDFk@vPvwwQBUffDqSrGWWMSt5L62b2DJAQpmsKPgFsKu8NJ@jWcvAfRRUbgMqyDNNnUqRr5I5f8aZYIXWR4m8auG6tjADBfmtuyZ27a5/YhSqKjYc0/fOcBdZjN3Zs8aLrfDRmPL@22THikgM8s5RE7u4xMM4NFtO7pfAbF@8uHvP/8CHLUMt/SVwqoahpePnpQ5KmOx0qsJa7SnDk6KJaZBchtO1icaIJ@wqVtx1ux@3ibV4So1EYAhs9RnTw6UTT2o8ywjjdlrwfGxwT9yDXVHo9uRN7z9eDnuX@9noOpfhZ/bKyezQlSwBY7sZz77sYmDz5TmlRFYPr6IhBSA/3m5Vj79F3mR7EKQfWqHl0Ib7Na0OlX0Jt673dDTyeD43fzDg4jN800zUvbNs38B) - PCRE2 v10.33 / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVXNbttGED4W0FOMGdTelahUkpHAEEULjizABhI5YGQ0jawQ1HIpEaFIglxGshtf8wC99pJLjzn3Wdpjn6TD3ZVEWy5K8Gd2dubbnZlvh79_Z2lU5OXjzhn7PjGaUcoy3mmeGNO_nGc-D8KYw9uBM-y4g6vzoXs9uhy7P1-ejy_gpPYsjFlU-Bx60un54rTGFl4GbjqZgg2O8Wq1-jQ7Ln65vX0_XrxcLcgfhQiaJ39-JDedfoPctOmXj2vawBfe67Wa_fuHPn3saJhQT203bbStyqq5yMJ4Xi6704UJarm3PN2zO62FsYAUReHyLEsywpI4FyC3XF_yPPfmnMKvufC7XYYW0OuBVpei1PPYjyzIuCiyGNrW_R5mOWaJz02YJUkEiR14UV7CymU03KTz4uXUqgFeYQBEZs-dc43haiuicIhK__Xg4sw5qVM9aUIe3vEkINuN_7TRVOwppXKV8iIJ9FUQLCkEdGEbKC3DM6QbyB10wXgUvHQ2DPQybmKDbvMRIHUWKpJtUmr3tSLOw3nMfYiSeK5eXpyveGbJhC1vXeZFEW5Dx65H7ixK2CeoMxM-J6EPdd8THuauTFIpgm0DKWfq9HCHQTV2o7GtTEtXZumFMUEAucF0gkSIeExS2mxP7ZalQlDsgJTZBul3DQulhp2qj0FJf4DPAUV9gYjHHVdgUdG3hJ-jIKGrQGGcFqJ0l4FhCaGe8c146Qm2cGUs9Z2s0DKeF5EwVQksfereXX4YSk0Q5BwnMV4MYS4WDwzqyWfOBHrpSuDp26y_TMOIE02Kd2_HDk3Zc-biZgk1NcaHoXPljofOm8vR2Xh4vlEP34-Ho_NyfCj3pL96Jy26Y_BBhgTUua-eBvnWdpXQ7b1suDj2BHeDLFm6qScEz2KSIctH169fa4CqDx5dwdcCk7iR7KfmNSzZQ8EIthTcQJgVXppP8ewxgFoqCpdhFaTZplbFyOep-F-jjLMiy8MkftJQLhvo5uLZLXNmt01m3qEUSir27OMXFjDbMz17Zs4aNjPDRmPD-02R7iggM8s-RI5u4iPcwJ3dtlS9AmL86MM_X38DbLUeTqkjhVnVDC8v1SlzVMZ8pUYTr9GeWtgplhgGyU04Wh8pgHziTe2Ks2L3wzLJClepiQAeMkveO3KgrPNBrQcRKcxeCw4PNf6BranrOFeOO7p6czYeXOx6oKxfhZ-bIyeyglewObbsBz67tomNT6fmiRZYXj6PuOCAf8BcKe__i7xIds7JLrT9Q6EMtmNa7SpqEs_dtumpYLD9qv_ot2_q-y8) - PCRE2 v10.40+

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXvbuJGEP/OU0x8arIL5gpcG0UYJ0oJUiLdkRNH1OsRzlrWa7DO2Ja9PkjafO0D9BH7IKXj3QWckKoWmNnZmd/On98OPE2bc843b3wRhLGAj/3RoOP1b68G3t3wZuz9enM1voaz2psw5lHhC@ilPBOdt4vzGl@wDLx0MgUXRtYvq9W32bvit4eHz@PF6WpBNl/JfeeiQe7b9I@va9rAF37W6w19aWrZUE9dL220nco5uczCeF4etNeFCWoFW54f2J3XwlhCiqL0RJYlGeFJnEtQQdaXIs/ZXFD4PZd@t8vRAno9MOpSVHoR@5EDmZBFFkPbeTrALNc88YUNsySJIHEDFuUlrDrGwE06P59OnRrgEwZAVL28uTAYnrEiGofogt/1ry9HZ3VqNm3Iw0eRBGQX@I9bTcWeUqpOKR@SwIVOgieFhC7sEqVlepZyAxVBF6wXyStny0Iv6z626K4eQVTkC53Jrii1p1oR5@E8Fj5ESTzXLxbnK5E5qmDLB4@zKMIwTO5m5c2ihH@DOrfhexL6UPeZZFi7skilCK4LpNyp0@M9BjXYjcauMy3TmSULY4IAKsB0gkSIRExS2mxP3ZajU9DsgJS7FrnoWg5KDTfVPxYlF338HlHUF4j4ruNJbCr6lvBzFBR0FSiM00KW7ioxbCHUM7FdL5nkC0/lUt/LGi0TeRFJW7fAMffs082XgdIEQS5wE/PFFOZy8cygnnwXXKKX6QTet@35yzSMBDGk@PRxPKIpf8s9DJZQ22B8GYxuvfFg9OFmeDkeXG3Vg8/jwfCqXB@rmMyviaRF9ww@ypCApvbV26Dexq6SuntQDQ/XTAovyJKllzIpRRaTDFk@vHv/3gBUffDqSrGWWMSt5L62b2DJAQpmsKPgFsKu8NJ@jWcvAfRRUbgMqyDNNnUqRr5I5f8aZYIXWR4m8auG6tjADBfmtuyZ27a5/YhSqKjYc386dYC7zGbuzJ41XG6HjcaW99smPVJAZpZziJzcxycYwKPbdnS/AmL94MPff/4FOGoZbukrhVU1DC8fPSlzVMZipVcT1mhPHZwUS0yD5DacrE80QD5hU7firNn9vE2qw1VqIgBDZqnPnhwom3pQ51lGGrPXguNjg3/kGuqORrcjb3j74XLcv97PQNW/Cj@3V05mhahgCxzZz3z2YxMHnynNKyOwfHwRCSkA//NyrXz6L/Ii2YUg@9QOL4U22K1pdaroTbx3u6Gnk8Hxu/mHBxGb55tmpOybZ/8C) - PCRE2 - every Fibonacci number up to \$F_{46}\$ in under 20 seconds

Instead of atomicizing the whole loop, as `^((?>\2?(\1)|x$|^x|\b))+`, we move all choices out of the loop, so there's only one thing it can do at any iteration. This saves 1 byte.

As in the PCRE1 version, we can change `|^x` to `|^xx` to return \$1\$ (instead of \$2\$) for an input of \$1\$.

An alternative 23 byte option would be `^(\2?+(\1)|x$|^x)+|^xxx`, but that'd be ever-so-slightly slower due to having an extra choice inside the loop.

## Regex (.NET), <s>33</s> 29 bytes

```
(?=(^(x)|\3?(\1)|)*)(?<-1>x)*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5NboMwEIX3nGKERsIDBQHdxXWJ1HVPkKSSIQ5YAowMFSg/2x6gR@xFqNuqymzm6XuL9w1mVnZsVNuuaMXOqloth82mVzPbBisrBHtjC133jwXbZ3SlkFjxFGfPC4VrsH3wX0w36FYdfeJ4Fin3TsYyZChdxlJkHLVIiQPquFWQ5z8pigguHrjDDgSgTV7lVDVqZMEShCiJ/5b6xPBMl9nqScWNGaebW8g43AHEvXGmre4V@Cjh6@MT3HaX1Na8D@MuPSSt6uupie4s/2fk/ylUAqWzkgJL98pIYMW92/oN)

Returns its output as the sum of the lengths of the match (group `\0`) and group `\2`. It is done as a sum because for inputs \$n=1,2,3\$ the Fibonacci index is \$n+1\$ and would not fit in a single capture group.

Group `\2`, which is `(x)` in this regex, is captured as \$1\$ iff the loop takes at least one iteration, which happens for all \$n>0\$. The loop count itself is also given an extra increment, as in the **23 byte** version above, by the addition of an empty alternative `|` inside the loop. This will result in a zero-width match being taken at the end, regardless of input; it even happens for \$n=0\$, but that doesn't matter, because the `(?<-1>x)*` will not have room to pop its capture, and the return match will be \$0\$ anyway.

Note that this regex would actually *not* be made shorter by returning its output as the sum of the lengths of `\0`, `\3`, and `\3`, as the shortest way I can think of to do that takes **34 bytes**:

```
(?=((?>\2?)(\1)|^x)*(x))?(?<-1>x)*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BboMwEEX3nMJCI2FDQUB3cR1H6ronSFLJkAlYMhgZKlDSbHuAHrEXoW6rKrOZP28W/w12Rje2aMwKTuwdNrgcN5seZ7qLVioFpXJ7KCWjh4K9vy4spgtjksqntNj6a412D@Gz7QZt8BQyDheR8@BsHQUKymeoRMFBi5xxAjo1SMryJyUJI9eA@IGOCAIue1FT3eJIoyWKQTH@@9RnChd2nZ2eMG3tON18Q8HJHZC0t17X6B5JCIp8fXwS391ljbNvw7jPj5nBvpna5M4e/1lcsvBPohagvJcSUPlVJQJqHtzWbw)

**38 byte** version that matches iff the input is a Fibonacci number:

```
^(?=(^(x)|(?>\3?)(\1)|)*x$|$)(?<-1>x)*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BboMwEEWvYlkjYUONINmFOETquicgRELUAUuOjYwRKMC2B@gRexEKraIs35/Rm/mN6YVta6HUApZnVlRiyA8HLXpy9pYrSTm5koFOJD1d9ikll5hO1B9gAkrSI4tPA/UX7/yG3829kUp8YprAg0fJzVhRlDUBhaRGIHXTOTpCwUGxtlHSYYYTeSNQhKXptGPKod22EHAosiifVwEBzTOpXf6XJKCZEk@ONw4COm6OOwcbfhSurEVLvMHzQdP/yYOOvZVOsNq0bl4/i5MXI6bN2lRJLRAGjX6@vhGstrCypmva9WaohK5cHbyy3TOjeJ7nJWLxPop@AQ)

## Regex (Perl / PCRE), 31 bytes

```
((?=(\2?x))(^x|\4?+(\3)))*(x|^)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLisJAEEX3fkUhhamyRWOPbmzLIDhbVy6DIQk@AjFK66LFx9IP8BPnR2JHZnMPBy7ntLHluD5cAa2BW3nM0xJwYLzKdDFfzWeP1vZoCc8S9jBtJpNhDwsJ/aeYykg3VIpvgLlg6i0VzDwyJZibFgAFLnCYszwHaJv0udM52aK6tOOqbXx5aODrvtAP4O/1hqBPhDoqN9Xuskc9CVnRv4y5q9k8kuR3uUiSmigSinXkmGnt7vEoUhT/MHOX3H3Ndf0B) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/BasMwDIbvfQoRBJEak7bpBgPX5LTBYKdd59akxm0CSWrcHALrrnuAPeJeJHPYYbCD@PUL6eOXr/20K33tAQMoSFYJ5OCDO5vgfFtZR@kqX5bG1FU7GHvpfNO6oEmz1K@rayogjXWKQ3N280I/uH64kjFPzy@PxrCADUdkBMvF6RIIK7UWeFQbgY1aS8Bmp7YPs2YZwzugVVhFWyk8RjlmCq1cwG@mrhpsTRjEdQhzQFcNlI6pQMsCO5bQnAgbdra@JLpPJMxdROYJfH9@QZJTPGxdT9i9FXvO/tz9npcFy49/jxLLiahUpItyZKbDeNN3ZUZ6y8xLGm8HnqYf) - PCRE

Returns its output as the sum of the lengths of groups `\2`, `\5`, and `\5`. The regex saves 3 bytes just by using a possessive quantifier, replacing `(?>\4?)` with `\4?+`.

The Fibonacci index minus \$2\$ is built up in `\2` using the expression `(?=(\2?x))`. The first time this is hit, the `\2?` will evaluate to zero because `\2` isn't set yet, and `\2` will be given a value of \$1\$. On every subsequent iteration, it will be incremented. This is done in a lookahead to avoid influencing the running total Fibonacci match, and is safe because at every step, the index will be less than the amount added to the full match.

The `(x|^)` at the end serves to let `\5`\$=1\$ in all cases except \$n=0\$.

This regex does not work under Java; group `\2` just captures \$1\$ and stays there. This may be due to a bug in Java's regex engine.

**33 byte** version that matches iff the input is a Fibonacci number:

```
^((?=(\2?x))(^x|\4?+(\3)))*(x|^)$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7BToNAFLz3KzbNS3dfgRZQEtNlC03q1ZM3KZtqqG6yUgRMMHQ9@gF@oj@CW9T4Di9vJjNvpipqHQ3PbwRqTnp9fNhrAktuoYi3m9vN2kwOx5pBI3werzn2RB0swr6qVdmSaVZOuSGpFk2lVcuoR93m9b5prUW6XuAGWLycRck/61seVyCRn381NnFfpzoOsU/1XbATdvs7biaEjMnqlwAVi1FgL8fB3noZ7WgHCsX7Euol9tDMZmOvsZbtHPCfmqAWlHx9fBK6YAzCRBflY/sE4cpHh0H0hyOL5yFyY4yU1zdbKYecsUSwLEw6RJZ3p@wycVh2gYhz1p1yhGHwvSvfzjc) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDBSsNAEL37FUNYyEyTpmm1F7chFxUK4kG9Ne1S47YpJJslSSHS9uoH@In@SJwURejCLjPz3puZtzaz3Sy2mQVRQQTOyIEAbKW3qtI2X6ca3VEwiJXK1nmj0rKwu1xXCSYkk@dR7frg8t1wUW11TzCNNk2NSj3MH@@VIh/GxC25sbzalBWKXRRKkUcbptf48no3fyJJB9htUOSLuqlybTii4XgZRU5iHGJyvX9jhMt@6A/H1Ot1a/PyXaMzdHymS9an5d40vXY2YdGCG/AbLuUVwHmy@c2FmUVnnCPPIx4NeLZcrJs0Q1H5PKz3r9cNuq3rC0O@KIjg0G@5I51mZb@aBHYzltDnIEzgwPfnFzgBoi5s84GiWEyWFIe3f7bOOXn/8PQC5pwGE5In3vl08elIslshxhEmk7glwlV7TG5iD5NrYhW2xxWJrguH05DPDw) - PCRE

If the output specification must be simplified to sum only two groups, this would be the shortest way I can think of doing it (**39 bytes**, output is the sum of the lengths of groups `\0` and `\5`):

```
(?=((?=(\2?x))(^x|\4?+(\3)))*(x))?\2?x?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLbsJADEX3fIWFLGIzPBIKq8EMSLDtih1poyTiESkENLAIArrsB/CJ/ZEw04Xv1bGtc97actIcb4BWw7085WkJONQOZbpcrBezZ2t3soQXCXuY@sgk6mEhofsppjIe@VaK74C5YOooFcxcZUow1y0ACuqgxpzlZ4jWqy@dztkW1bUdV23tzJGGf3aGQQB/vy8IBkRztQm/@vO@S1blttpfDzhh/UyS1ecySRoyQn7ikamZ6bt@xGOjKP5g5i65lfEX0zRv) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU9BTsMwELz3FatopawbK00pHMC1fAIJiRNXApZruU2kJLVcH4qAKw/giXwk2OKAxGE1O7s7o1nf@XmrfOcBA0goVgXU4IM76OD8YKyjclUvldadGaK2x9H3gwsttUy0j6tTyaFMtU9DfXD5YIpuiifS@u7@4VZrxmHNkmUyFov9MRAa2XDcyTXHXjYCsN/KzXXGqmLwBmglmkSNxF2CXSXRigX8ZhpNtB1h4KcYckBnIpXnkqNlHEcmoN8T9szZ7li0UyEgd8myLuD78wuKmpJwcBPh@NQ8s4rc6ONrZlfPTDU3f9vEGRMf//4mJmZSknK1F@rMGL2c39tLVVG7SYIlpZHKGzXPPw) - PCRE

**42 byte** version that matches iff the input is a Fibonacci number:

```
^(?=((?=(\2?x))(^x|\4?+(\3)))*(x|^)$)\2?x?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5dT4MwFH3fr2iWZu0VGGVKYla6smS@@uSbjGYapk0qQ8AE0@GjP8Cf6B/Bgibe5N7cc@7HOVVRm3h4eUe45sia0@PBIBxyB0Wy295tN/3seKopbgTjyYaDRfroENiq1mWL5lk55z1KjWgqo1tKAuI3bw9N606UH0R@BMXruCT/WeZ4WGMFfPzVOMVDnZpkBTY199FeuMr2vJ8hNCnrPwLrREwLrvM8sO6Wko50WIP4CHEdgsXNYjH5mmw5zxH/tYn1kqDvzy9ElpSmnnsXpIGr4FEcS1OUT@0zjtcMgPd9r9TN7U6pIadS0DGzlewAaN6dsyvp0ewSAC5od84BwziTw8CCa@biBw) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDBaoNAEL3nKwZZcCZRo2lz2oiXthAoPbS9xWSxdhMDZhU1ICS59gP6if0ROxtaCl2YZWbnvXnzti7qYZHURQ2igRicqQMB1I3eqUbXZZZrdKfBOFGqyMpO5dWh3pe6STElmT5PW9cDl2PLj2qnLcB02nQtKvWwfLxXijyIiEfyYDnaVg2KfRxKUcZbhrf48nq3fCJJJ9hvUZSrtmtKbTgjP1rHsZMahxjcHt@4w89e6PkRWb7u67J61@j4jsdwyfy8OprOchczJq14AN/hWo4ArsrmpxZmEV/7nE0mxNKAV8uHrMsLFI3HYta/zjp0e9cThjxxIIKT3XJPOi8qu5oEdhNJsDUIEzjw9fEJToC/Ng4sR5O/ar4mkhfe5/LvQ5HksMEkRhvpLOmJcNOf09tkgukNEY2xP29IkO0lwxD685DPNw) - PCRE

Answer (score 4):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 90 bytes

*Written in conversation with [flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr) in chat.*

```
F-N-A-B:-F=A;N>0,M is N-1,C is A+B,F-M-B-C.
F/N/I:-N=I,F-N-0-1;J is I+1,F/N/J.
F/N:-F/N/0.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxLCoQwEAX3nsK9/ZI0gcEPERIhEMG@hAsRBhx04fGjmV3Bq3q/8/geG657zzlC4BF6ROcHGQ0t9X7VAqapgG8CRSwImFQVtejUQ1yikhnwMBcpNUxlm//Ke/WyUTlzaz@WuTNWi6rWBw)

#### Ungolfed

Here's a less-golfed version:

```
fib(F,0,F,_).
fib(F,N,A,B) :- N>0, M is N-1, C is A+B, fib(F,M,B,C).
fibindex(F,N,N) :- fib(F,N,0,1).
fibindex(F,N,I) :- J is I+1, fibindex(F,N,J).
fibindex(F,N) :- fibindex(F,N,0).
```

The `fib/4` predicate (`F-N-A-B` in the golfed version) takes a number `N` and two accumulators `A` and `B` (which should start at `0` and `1`) and unifies `F` with the `N`th Fibonacci number. If `N` is `0`, `F` is simply the current value of `A`, the smaller accumulator value. Otherwise, count `N` down by one and recurse with new accumulator values `B` and `A+B`.

`fibindex/3` (`F/N/I` in the golfed version) takes a Fibonacci number `F` and an index `I` (which should start at `0`) and unifies `N` with the Fibonacci index of `F`. Either `F` is the `I`th Fibonacci number, in which case `N=I` and we're done, or we count `I` up by one and recurse. Note that this approach leads to infinite recursion if given a non-Fibonacci number, but we don't have to handle that case for this challenge.

Finally, `fibindex/2` (`F/N`) just calls `fibindex/3` with an initial `I` value of `0`.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 38 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a=0,b=1:n^a and-~f(n,b,a+b)
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/fAT2fL).

Answer (score 3):

## C, <strike>62</strike> 58 bytes

```C
g(c,a,b){return c-a?g(c,b,a+b)+1:0;}f(c){return g(c,0,1);}
```

**Detailed**

```C
int g(int c, int a, int b)
{
    if (c == a)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return g(c, b, a+b) + 1;
    }
}

int f(c)
{
    return g(c, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY/RbsIwDEWfyVcYEFIi3Cmha2F0ZT@ylzZJRyQIqE0nJMa3d0mLNGVPcY7te69l4qQchi8qscKa3Vvt@taCTKqPwGqs1jVbiz0vHmSpdGOshoZKFpocBRuWxspTrzS8d06Zy8vxQIixjjjdOeoLMBYhvPp21dIxciez8G11159cQWZTAaWXNZZ5cG19v6GLlYLkACv1aRc4qkyTfiQsjTGfu/PyqV6Qx@R@royl3xej/vy8Aw928FPCGI4jcBaRDUIakxThNSYZQhaTHUIeE@HXtv/QLs1TId54UMyjG3zo4Rc)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, 70 bytes

```
int c(int n){int a=0,b=1,c=0,t;while(a<n){c++;t=b;b+=a;a=t;}return c;}
```

https://ideone.com/I4rUC5

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, nice first answer!

Comment: `int c(int n){int a=0,b=1,c=0,t;for(;a<n;t=b,b+=a,a=t)c++;return c;}` (not tested)

Comment: `int c(int n){int a=0,b=1,c=0;while(a<n){c++;b+=a;a=b-a;}return c;}` (not tested)

Comment: `int c(int n){int a=0,b=1,c=0;for(;a<n;b+=a,a=b-a)c++;return c;}` (not tested)

Answer (score 2):

### TSQL, 143 bytes

Input goes in `@n` as in `DECLARE @n INT = 1836311903;`

```
DECLARE @O BIGINT=0;WITH F(R,P,N)AS(SELECT @O,@O,@O+1 UNION ALL SELECT R+1,N,P+N FROM F WHERE N<=@n)SELECT MAX(R)FROM F OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 45 bytes

```
f x=round$log(sqrt 5*x+0.9)/log((sqrt 5+1)/2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Sesos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/sesos), 28 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0000000: 16f8be 766ef7 ae6d80 f90bde b563f0 7ded18 3ceffa  ...vn..m.....c.}..<..
0000015: b1c1bb af9f3f ff                                  .....?.
```

[Try it online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=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&input=NQ&debug=on)

(Exponential time because in Sesos copying a number needs exponential time.)

Assembly used to generate the binary file:

```lisp
set numin
set numout
get
jmp
sub 1
fwd 1
add 1
fwd 1
add 1
rwd 2
jnz    ;input input
fwd 4
add 1  ;input input 0 1
fwd 2
add 1  ;input input 0 1 0 1
rwd 4
jmp
jmp    ;input input-curr curr next iterations
sub 1
jnz    ;input 0 curr next iterations
fwd 3
add 1
jmp
sub 1
fwd 2
add 1
rwd 2
jnz    ;input 0 curr next 0 0 iterations+1
rwd 1
jmp
sub 1
fwd 1
add 1
fwd 1
add 1
rwd 2
jnz    ;input 0 curr 0 next next iterations+1
rwd 1
jmp
sub 1
fwd 1
sub 1
fwd 2
add 1
rwd 3
jnz    ;input 0 0 -curr next curr+next iterations+1
rwd 2
jmp
sub 1
fwd 2
add 1
fwd 1
add 1
rwd 3
jnz    ;0 0 input input-curr next curr+next iterations+1
fwd 3
jnz
fwd 3
put
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8 61 bytes

Same as @dainichi answer only made shorter by using Java 8 lambdas. The answer is a valid rvalue expression.

```
n->{int a=0,b=1,c=0,t;while(a<n){c++;t=b;b+=a;a=t;}return c;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
interface F
{
    int c(int n);
}

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        F f = n->{int a=0,b=1,c=0,t;while(a<n){c++;t=b;b+=a;a=t;}return c;};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 14 bytes

```
≜∧0;1⟨t≡+⟩ⁱ↖?h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVsApP9icmFjaHlsb2cy/3t3IiAtPiAidz9@4oaw4oKC4bqJfeG1kP/iiZziiKcwOzHin6h04omhK@KfqeKBseKGlj9o//9bMCwyLDMsNSw4LDEzLDE4MzYzMTE5MDNd)

Takes input through the output variable and outputs through the input variable.

```
≜                 Label the input variable, trying 0, 1, -1, 2...,
  0               then starting with 0
 ∧                (which is not necessarily the input variable)
   ;1             paired with 1,
     ⟨t≡ ⟩        replace the first element of the pair with the last element
     ⟨ ≡+⟩        and the last element of the pair with the sum of the elements
          ⁱ↖?     a number of times equal to the input variable,
             h    such that the first element of the pair is the output variable.
```

I'm not entirely sure why `≜` is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 14 bytes

```apl
(+.!∘⌽⍨∘⍳¨…)⍳⊢
```

Explanation soon (TM)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OApIa2nuKjjhmPevY@6l0BYvRuPrTiUcMyTSDjUdcikGqgqjQFU1MuGNMIzjL@DwA)

Comment: I think four months is longer than "soon"

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
ÞFḟ›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiw55G4bif4oC6IiwiIiwiMFxuMVxuMVxuMlxuM1xuNVxuOFxuMTNcbjIxXG4zNFxuNTVcbjg5XG4xNDRcbjIzM1xuMzc3XG42MTBcbjk4N1xuMTU5N1xuMjU4NFxuNDE4MVxuNjc2NVxuMTA5NDZcbjE3NzExXG4yODY1N1xuNDYzNjhcbjc1MDI1XG4xMjEzOTNcbjE5NjQxOFxuMzE3ODExXG41MTQyMjlcbjgzMjA0MFxuMTM0NjI2OVxuMjE3ODMwOVxuMzUyNDU3OFxuNTcwMjg4N1xuOTIyNzQ2NVxuMTQ5MzAzNTJcbjI0MTU3ODE3XG4zOTA4ODE2OVxuNjMyNDU5ODZcbjEwMjMzNDE1NVxuMTY1NTgwMTQxXG4yNjc5MTQyOTZcbjQzMzQ5NDQzN1xuNzAxNDA4NzMzIl0=)

-2 thanks to Deadcode

1 byte longer than it should be just because Vyxal's "Fibonacci sequence" builtin does not start with 0.

Comment: Why didn't you just do `ÞFḟ›` for [4 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiw55G4bif4oC6IiwiIiwiMFxuMVxuMVxuMlxuM1xuNVxuOFxuMTNcbjIxXG4zNFxuNTVcbjg5XG4xNDRcbjIzM1xuMzc3XG42MTBcbjk4N1xuMTU5N1xuMjU4NFxuNDE4MVxuNjc2NVxuMTA5NDZcbjE3NzExXG4yODY1N1xuNDYzNjhcbjc1MDI1XG4xMjEzOTNcbjE5NjQxOFxuMzE3ODExXG41MTQyMjlcbjgzMjA0MFxuMTM0NjI2OVxuMjE3ODMwOVxuMzUyNDU3OFxuNTcwMjg4N1xuOTIyNzQ2NVxuMTQ5MzAzNTJcbjI0MTU3ODE3XG4zOTA4ODE2OVxuNjMyNDU5ODZcbjEwMjMzNDE1NVxuMTY1NTgwMTQxXG4yNjc5MTQyOTZcbjQzMzQ5NDQzN1xuNzAxNDA4NzMzIl0=)?

Comment: You forgot to change the code in the code block.

Answer (score 2):

## [C89 (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 54 bytes

```c
a,b,r;g(f){for(a=r=0,b=1;a<f;++r)b+=a,a=b-a;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9RT8MgFIWfx6@4ziwp6a2hq6szjP0SX2hLK0mlC6XGZO63VxgmBp@4fJx7zqEt2lGaYV0lNmj5kPX02k82k8IKho0ouTz1PM8tbXIhUYqmkNwqt1gDlt/WR23acekUnGbX6enp/UyINo44NbvMD6ANQjjV10W1jpIr2YSrVfMyOk42cQABg5dTDy7Wv/fZdtdBcYZd92a2eHeJSi8JS7FA3H0Qv@6c3GL6h9Qm@5x095fnE1iIg28B93IMgdGE7BGqlFQIzyk5IBxSckSoU1L6tZd/6FjVVVm@suBYJ3/wpdcf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ô!gM è<U
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9CFnTSDoPFU&input=MTM)

### Original, 9 bytes

Can handle larger inputs than the version above.

```
nMgV°)©Òß
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bk1nVrApqdLf&input=MTgzNjMxMTkwMw)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
J1tf>=Z+~JZZQ
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J1tf%3E%3DZ%2B~JZZQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A5%0A8%0A13%0A1836311903&debug=0)

Approximation in Python 2:

```python
Z=0;J=1;T=1;Q=input()
while not J+Z>Q:
    temp=J
    J=Z
    Z=temp+J
    T += 1
print(T-1)
```

#### alternative approach, 18 bytes

```
L?<b2bsyMtBtbs.IyG
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3F%3Cb2bsyMtBtbs.IyG&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A5%0A8%0A13%0A1836311903&debug=0)

This uses `.I` for inverse.

Answer (score 1):

## J, <s>32</s> <s>27</s> 17 bytes

```
i.~0,+/@(!|.)\@i.
```

Computes the first *n* Fibonacci numbers and then finds the index of *n* in that list.

### Usage

Extra commands are used for formatting multiple input/output. The last test case is omitted since it will require much more time to compute.

```
   f =: i.~0,+/@(!|.)\@i.
   (,.f"0) 0 1 2 3 5 8 13
 0 0
 1 1
 2 3
 3 4
 5 5
 8 6
13 7
```

### Explanation

```
i.~0,+/@(!|.)\@i.  Input: n
               i.  Get the range [0, 1, ..., n-1]
             \@    For each prefix of that range
          |.         Reverse the prefix
         !           Find the binomial coefficient between each value in the original
                     prefix and the reversed prefix
     +/@             Sum those binomial coefficients
                   This will create the Fibonacci numbers from 1 to n
   0,              Prepend a 0 to the list of Fibonacci numbers
i.~                Find the index of n in that list and return
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 89 bytes

```
int c(int n){int i=-1;while(f(++i)<n);return i;}int f(int n){return n<2?n:f(n-1)+f(n-2);}
```

Inspired by the explanation of [*@Adnan*'s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85571/52210).

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/KTzX1a) (Time limit exceeded for last test case, but it works in about 30-45 seconds on my PC.)

```
class Main{
  static int c(int n){
    int i = -1;
    while(f(++i) < n);
    return i;
  }

  static int f(int n){
    return n < 2
             ? n
             : f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(0));
    System.out.println(c(2));
    System.out.println(c(3));
    System.out.println(c(5));
    System.out.println(c(8));
    System.out.println(c(1836311903));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
3
4
5
6
46
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 5.10, 48 bytes

Basically looking for the right `n` so that `F(n) = input`.

`-a` switch adds one byte.

```
$b++;while($_>$a){$c=$a;$a+=$b;$b=$c;$n++}say$n
```

[Try it here!](https://ideone.com/A6knTh)

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
‘RḶUc$S€i
```

Finds the first *n*+1 Fibonacci numbers and locates the index of *n* in that list.

Note: This is very inefficient and large test cases should not be run on the online interpreter.

[Try it here.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCYUuG4tlVjJFPigqxp&input=&args=MTM)

### Explanation

```
‘RḶUc$S€i  Input: n
‘          Increment n
 R         Generate the range [1, 2, ..., n+1]
           For each value x in that range
  Ḷ          Create the range [0, 1, ..., x-1]
   U         Create a reversed copy
    c        Compute the binomial coefficient between each pair of values
     $       Combine the last two links (Uc) as a monad
      S€   Sum each list of binomial coefficients
           This will result in a list of the first n+1 Fibonacci numbers
        i  Find the index of n in that list and return
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 30 bytes

```
Round@Log[5^.5/2+.5,.8+5^.5#]&
```

Pure function; returns 2 if the input is 1.

Doesn't beat the other Mathematica entry, but showcases an unusual method: It's a (very cool) fact that the Nth Fibonacci number is the closest integer to [1/sqrt(5) times the Nth power of the golden ratio] ("Binet's formula").

Therefore the inverse function will be the base-[golden ratio] logarithm of [sqrt(5) times the Fibonacci number in question]. The `.8+` is a hack to make sure we don't take the logarithm of 0, without screwing up the other values.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 38 bytes

```
{a=c=0;b=1;for(;a<it;b+=(a=b-a))c++;c}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

```
Lo æ@U¥MgX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@@@Tr3B4mUPooaW@6RH//xtaGJsZGxpaGhgDAA)

### Explanation

```
Lo æ@U¥MgX
Lo           // Creates a range from 0 to 99
   æ@        // Iterates through the range. Returns the first item X where:
     U¥      //   Input ==
       MgX   //   Xth Fibonacci number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
‘ÆḞ€i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4zDbQ93zHvUtCbz/@F2IPX/v4GOkY6xjqmOhY6hMQA)

Nothing special here, just an updated version of Jelly

### How it works

```
‘ÆḞ€i - Main link. Takes n on the left
‘     - Yield n+1
   €  - For each k = 1, 2, ..., n+1:
 ÆḞ   -   Yield the k'th Fibonacci number
    i - Return the index of n in this list
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code, System V calling convention, 16 bytes

```
31 c0 99 6a 01 59 0f c1 d1 ff c0 39 fa 75 f7 c3
```

In assembly:

```
fib:
    # initialize registers: rax=0, rdx=0, rcx=1
    xor eax,eax
    cdq
    push 1
    pop rcx
fib_loop: 
    # add registers and swap over and over 
    # until the result equals the input
    xadd ecx,edx
    inc eax
    cmp edx,edi
    jne fib_loop
    ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbbtswDH02v4JoMOwlMeqkW9sA3cuA/cQ2GLRFO2plyZPkxvn6jLaSrAlmwDYv5xxSpCgE7ipzWLV1fVxQ8jjgfkeR39mjDqgtfneKMXAdtbNIVqEbYj9EHEeFjfMdRVgox8F@jrh3/g11g/XEEboh34pQ3JHFXveM1dA07GFRiYAICmGinRQFFrEb6p2UOezpALm2kU0ZDjbSiNb1nhs9Qq4oEoRIPpantg/bY6OrLaA8/RB2WCTT9ehpnO1a/QHBlMa5PgHHetci07hklSCkFIq95DOl65Ov9OxPVMt4VrkRqRPJ8uzPtud4ZKv@dQlnqzRsXz6mVtfnAQg12aYM0WvbbiHLk4V3n4Zf9g56ceL/0/jyDRNIalwQ0JA2g@ey4xCo5S1cKD8kwyqfGDeguUvMcYU3CYA88hjl1xpXkcGOtIXpI72EoUIf@uXTHDgNPOvcu0T1UjKQGSb0Si9/fjzlb8hqMgbnGGSRQ0yTlWlmr4ZR5pV0eKKK0JkhG4Hsap0JFi6wS8GrwZ35KShFZOGXnkHKSd/TpUinyaZ1FrCGdQGbByge5H3afN0UxfP9BmH9/Fisiy/3j5u/)

Explicitly computes the nth Fibonacci number in `ecx` and `edx`, while keeping track of the count in `eax`. Takes input in `rdi` and returns in `rax`, as usual for 64-bit x86.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (using external library) (84 bytes)

```
n=>_.Until((i,a)=>{l=a.length;if(a[l-1]!=n){return i<=1?i:a[l-1]+a[l-2]}}).Count()-1
```

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable

Code explanation: Library has static method that creates a sequence until the predicate has an undefined return value. The predicate has a signature of ("i"ndex, current internal "a"rray generated). At each iteration, we check if the last element of the internal array is equal to the input, n. If not, return the next value in the fib sequence. Otherwise, the predicate has an undefined result which terminates the generation of the sequence. Then, we return the length of the sequence (and subtract 1 in order to comply with the 0 based-ness as seen in the OP

[image]

Comment: 53 Bytes by using code from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98699/74284) ```n=>{a=c=t=0,b=1;while(a<n){c++;t=b;b+=a;a=t}return c}``` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LclBD4IgGIDhO7/iWycZ2CRWs9HnH3EekGFpDhqS2Zy/nTx0eQ/PO@hZTyb0r5jPZeowOaxWjQYjFrxFoT6PfrSZvjm6GsZUxFa1DLXSGLdg4zs4MFuadYAFEOqCn7jkZ15yIbko5UUKcS1kowjpfIDsab/QO1gorATAeDf50R5Hf8@Wen8NMDhAXu1h0P2NUkW29AM)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 130 Bytes

Golfed:

```
int F(int n){var a=new int[4];a[1]=1;int i=0;while(a[3]<n){a[3]=a.ToList().GetRange(1,2).Sum();a[1]=a[2];a[2]=a[3];i++;}return i;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public int F(int n)
{
  var a = new int[4];

  a[1] = 1;

  int i = 0;

  while (a[3] < n)
  {
    a[3] = a.ToList().GetRange(1, 2).Sum();

    a[1] = a[2];
    a[2] = a[3];

    i++;
  }

  return i;
}
```

Test:

```
var fibonacciReversed = new FibonacciReversed();

var fr = fibonacciReversed.F(0);
Console.WriteLine(fr);
0

fr = fibonacciReversed.F(2);
Console.WriteLine(fr);
3

fr = fibonacciReversed.F(3);
Console.WriteLine(fr);
4

fr = fibonacciReversed.F(5);
Console.WriteLine(fr);
5

fr = fibonacciReversed.F(8);
Console.WriteLine(fr);
6

fr = fibonacciReversed.F(13);
Console.WriteLine(fr);
7

fr = fibonacciReversed.F(1836311903);
Console.WriteLine(fr);
46
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 58 bytes

```
{for(n[++j]++;n[j]<$1;n[++j]=n[j]+n[j-1]){}j=$0?j:0;$0=j}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SCMvWls7K1Zb2zovOivWRsXQGiJgC@JqAwldw1jN6tosWxUD@ywrA2sVA9usWsP//w0tjM2MDQ0tDYwVAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `project-euler.002`, <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```factor
[ dup fib-upto index ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCsIwEAXQfU/xL9CSdFCqHkDcuBFX4qKmU4i2SZxOQBHPHn3rN/ZOo5Tz6XDcb5Ek3tlpzXliaYxpsfAzc3C84MESePoXVn0n8UGxq6oPDFoQVuhgCbajNVm7MYRvuWDICaO/1TlphA8Dv3Atc5/QlB8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ĖÆFȮ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCU5NiVDMyU4NkYlQzglQUUmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xMyZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
ĖÆFȮ  # Implicit input
Ė     # Push [0..input] to the stack
 ÆF   # nth Fibonacci number for each
   Ȯ  # Index of input in this list
      # Implicit output
```