# Am I a Fibonacci Number?

Tags: code-golf, sequence, decision-problem, fibonacci

### Your Task:

Write a program or function to check if a number that is inputted is a [*Fibonacci number*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)  A Fibonacci number is a number contained in the Fibonacci sequence.

The Fibonacci Sequence is defined as:
`F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2)`

With the seeds being `F(0) = 0` and `F(1) = 1`.

### Input:

A non-negative integer between 0 and 1,000,000,000 that may or may not be a Fibonacci number.

### Output:

A truthy/falsy value indicating whether or not the input is a Fibonacci number.

### Examples:

```
0-->truthy
1-->truthy
2-->truthy
12-->falsy
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte count wins.

Comment: The programming language I'm using only supports numbers up to 9999 (Geometry Dash). Is it okay if I assume that it does support numbers up to 1000000, theoretically?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim/wiki/Code-Page)

```
f
```

Explanation:

```
f       Push an infinite fibonacci list
       Is the input in that list?
```

Works the same as my [It's Hip to be Square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125250/26600) answer, but uses a different infinite list: `f`, for fibonacci.

[Try  it!](http://178.62.56.56:80/neim?code=f%F0%9D%95%9A&input=0)

Comment: Wow!  Impressive score.

Comment: That's great, but not 2 bytes. In UTF-8 it's represented as "66 F0 9D 95 9A"

Comment: @sm4rk0 That's great, but you're wrong. [Neim uses a custom codepage](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim/wiki/Code-Page), so the byte representation of this is `66 D5`

Comment: Doesn't this loop forever if the input is not in the list? If so, does that count as falsey?

Comment: @EnricoBorba Neim knows that the nth element in this infinite list will always be equal to or less than the n+1th element in the list. Therefore, it can catch itself and it will not run forever. Have you tried the program it? :P

Comment: That's awesome! Just tried it now.

Comment: Congrats on the shortest code.  Since this challenge has been up for nearly a week, its time to mark the accepted answer, and this is it!

Answer (score 19):

## Regex (ECMAScript), <s>392</s> <s>358</s> <s>328</s> <s>224</s> <s>206</s> <s>165</s> <s>164</s> <s>162</s> 161 bytes

*-1 byte by using ECMAScript non-participating capture group behavior*
*-2 bytes by by calculating \$F_{2n+3}\$ differently*
*-1 byte by moving around a remainder*

The techniques that need to come into play to match Fibonacci numbers with an ECMAScript regex (in unary) are a far cry from how it's best done in most other regex flavors. The lack of forward/nested backreferences or recursion means that it is impossible to directly count or keep a running total of anything. The lack of lookbehind makes it often a challenge even to have enough space to work in.

Many problems must be approached from an entirely different perspective, and seem unsolvable until the arrival of some key insight. It forces you to cast a much wider net in finding which mathematical properties of the numbers you're working with might be able to be used to make a particular problem solvable.

In March 2014, this is what happened for Fibonacci numbers. Looking at the Wikipedia page, I initially couldn't figure out a way, though one particular property seemed tantalizingly close. Then the mathematician [teukon](https://gist.github.com/teukon) outlined a method that made it quite clear it would be possible to do, using that property along with another one. He was reluctant to actually construct the regex. His reaction when I went ahead and did it:

> You're crazy! ... I thought you might do this.

As with my other ECMAScript unary math regex posts, I'll give a **warning:** I highly recommend learning how to solve unary mathematical problems in ECMAScript regex. It's been a fascinating journey for me, and I don't want to spoil it for anybody who might potentially want to try it themselves, especially those with an interest in number theory. [See that post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178889/17216) for a list of consecutively spoiler-tagged recommended problems to solve one by one.

So **do not read any further if you don't want some unary regex magic spoiled for you**. If you do want to take a shot at figuring out this magic yourself, I highly recommend starting by solving some problems in ECMAScript regex as outlined in that post linked above.

The challenge I initially faced: A positive integer *x* [is a Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Identification) if and only if 5x<sup>2</sup> + 4 and/or 5x<sup>2</sup> - 4 is a perfect square. But there is no room to calculate this in a regex. The only space we have to work in is the number itself. We don't even have enough room to multiply by 5 *or* take the square, let alone both.

teukon's idea on how to solve it ([originally posted here](https://gist.github.com/Davidebyzero/9090628#gistcomment-1185682)):

> The regex is presented with a string of the form `^x*$`, let z be its length.  Check whether or not z is one of the first few Fibonacci numbers by hand (up to 21 should do).  If it is not:
>
> 1. Read a couple of numbers, a  Use forward look-aheads to build a<sup>2</sup>, ab, and b<sup>2</sup>.
>
>    Assert that either 5a<sup>2</sup> + 4 or 5a<sup>2</sup> - 4 is a perfect square (so a must be F<sub>n-1</sub> for some n).
>
>    Assert that either 5b<sup>2</sup> + 4 or 5b<sup>2</sup> - 4 is a perfect square (so b must be F<sub>n</sub>).
>
>    Check that z = F<sub>2n+3</sub> or z = F<sub>2n+4</sub> by using the earlier built a<sup>2</sup>, ab, and b<sup>2</sup>, and the identities:
>
>    - F<sub>2n-1</sub> = F<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> + F<sub>n-1</sub><sup>2</sup>
>
>      F<sub>2n</sub> = (2F<sub>n-1</sub> + F<sub>n</sub>)F<sub>n</sub>
>
> In brief: these identities allow us to reduce the problem of checking that a given number is Fibonacci to checking that a pair of **much** smaller numbers are Fibonacci.  A little algebra will show that for large enough n (n = 3 should do), F<sub>2n+3</sub> > F<sub>n</sub> + 5F<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> + 4 so there should always be enough space.

And [here is a mockup of the algorithm in C](https://gist.github.com/Davidebyzero/9090628#gistcomment-1185782) which I wrote as a test before implementing it in regex. My final golfed regex is rather different. There turned out to be no need to find both \$a\$ and \$b\$, because \$b\$ is the Lucas number \$L_n\$, which along with \$F_n\$ can be used to derive \$F_{2n+2}\$ and \$F_{2n+3}\$ as needed:

- \${L_n}^2 = 5{F_n}^2±4\$
- \$L_{2n} = ({5{F_n}^2 + {L_n}^2}) / 2 = 5{F_n}^2±2 = {L_n}^2∓2\$
- \$F_{2n} = L_n F_n\$
- \$F_{2n+1} = ({L_{2n} + F_{2n}})/2\$
- \$F_{2n+2} = F_{2n} + F_{2n+1}\$
- \$F_{2n+3} = F_{2n+1} + F_{2n+2}\$

So with no further ado, here is the regex:

`^(?=(x*).*(?=x{4}(x{5}(\1{5}))(?=\2*$)\3+$)(|x{4})(?=xx(x*)\5)\4(x(x*))(?=(\6*)\7+$)(?=\6*$\8)\6*(?=x\1\7+$)(x*)(\9x?)|)(\9\10(\5\10)\12?|xx?x?|x{5}|x{8}|x{21})$`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9BTwIxEIX/ChICM4ssuwiIrGVPHrhw0KPVpIGyVEvZtAUqu/vbsdWYeHkz@d6bvMwHOzGz1qK0A1OKDdf7g/rkX1dNFD@3nnnx5EqAC1kMo@s75ARchHHkF1eNG3DVpAGaekX0jI6iDtK7fgehDn5gzoUTOkE6hp81QKBTz@5D0F9Now6doR8hTtNf7pNAH1yOdZg0TYBOvCJNR3ntXO68@l4vsyCjtMHONRpeMLaHF6uFKgBjI8Waw/R2MEbMDEmy805IDiCJ5mwjheKAeEPUUUqsCiJjU0phoTfoYSa2AIoUseSqsDtcjOpamBVbgSAl04YvlYXiNXlD/DP4f0Mt0jydBxvtTh/O7aU6MSk2Lc1Uweetdl9m24OGTDwSnol@H31h27VjzUvOLAiM98yud6ARK9Ptlv4lC@GLNCuP1ljtI1nTXJPBOEm@AQ)

And the pretty-printed, commented version:

```
^                          # tail = N = input number
(?=
    (x*)                   # \1+1 = potential number for which 5*(\1+1)^2 ± 4 is a
                           # perfect square; this is true iff \1+1 is a Fibonacci number,
                           # which we shall call F_n. Outside the surrounding lookahead
                           # block, \1+1 is guaranteed to be the largest number for which
                           # this is true such that \1 + 5*(\1+1)^2 + 4 <= N.
    .*
    (?=                    # tail = (\1+1) * (\1+1) * 5 + 4
        x{4}
        (                  # \2 = (\1+1) * 5
            x{5}
            (\1{5})        # \3 = \1 * 5
        )
        (?=\2*$)
        \3+$
    )
    (|x{4})                # \4 = parity - determined by whether the index of Fibonacci
                           #               number \1+1 is odd or even;
    (?=
        xx                 # tail = arithmetic mean of (\1+1) * (\1+1) * 5 and \6 * \6
                           #      = ((F_n * F_n * 5) + (L_n * L_n)) / 2 = L_{2n}
        (x*)\5             # \5 = floor(tail / 2) = floor(L_{2n} / 2)
    )
    \4
    # require that the current tail is a perfect square
    (x(x*))                # \6 = potential square root, which will be the square root
                           #      after the following two lookaheads; \7 = \6-1
    (?=(\6*)\7+$)          # \8 = must be zero for \6 to be a valid square root
    (?=\6*$\8)
    # \6 is now the Lucas number L_n corresponding to the Fibonacci number F_n.
    \6*
    (?=x\1\7+$)            # tail = F_{2n} = L_n * F_n = \6 * (\1+1), where \6 is larger
    (x*)(\9x?)             # \9 = floor(tail / 2);
                           # \10 = ceil(tail / 2); the remainder tail % 2 will always be
                           #       the same as the remainder discarded by \5, because
                           #       F_{2n} is odd iff L_{2n} is odd, thus this ceil()
                           #       can complement the floor() of \5 when adding \5 + \10
|                          # Allow everything above to be skipped, resulting in all
                           # capture groups being unset.
)
(
    # Note that if the above was skipped using the empty alternative in the lookahead,
    # the following will evaluate to 0. This relies on ECMAScript NPCG behavior.
    \9\10(\5\10)           # \12  = F_{2n+1} = (L_{2n} + F_{2n})/2 = \5 + \10;
                           # head = F_{2n+2} = F_{2n}   + F_{2n+1}
                           #                 = \9+\10   +   \12
    \12?                   # head = F_{2n+3} = F_{2n+2} + F_{2n+1}    (optionally)
                           #                 = head     +   \12
|
    xx?x?|x{5}|x{8}|x{21}  # The Fibonacci numbers 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 21 cannot be handled
                           # by our main algorithm, so match them here; note, as it so
                           # happens the main algorithm does match 13, so that doesn't
                           # need to be handled here.
)$
```

The multiplication algorithm is not explained in those comments, but is briefly explained in a paragraph of my [abundant numbers regex post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178952/17216).

I was maintaining six different versions of the Fibonacci regex: four that ratchet from shortest length to fastest speed and use the algorithm explained above, and two others that use a different, much faster but much more lengthy algorithm, which as I found can actually return the Fibonacci index as a match (explaining that algorithm here is beyond the scope of this post, but it's explained [in the original discussion Gist](https://gist.github.com/Davidebyzero/9090628#gistcomment-1186893)). I don't think I would maintain that many very-similar versions of a regex again, because at the time I was doing all my testing in PCRE and Perl, but [my regex engine](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine) is fast enough that concerns of speed are not as important anymore (and if a particular construct is causing a bottleneck, I can add an optimization for it) – though I'd probably again maintain one fastest version and one shortest version, if the difference in speed were big enough.

The "return the Fibonacci index minus 1 as a match" version (not heavily golfed):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLBcpswEP0Vx@OJtVATJMDYpphTD7nk0B6rdoZJFKwWYwZIoga49gP6if0RVyvH4E47owGt9r23b1f6lj6n9X0ly2ZRl/JBVPtD8V38OFZxIV4mH0X2QZWEvMbbG@v4lSQbksS4FFF2AoBbx8Ifp9YMCGf2DE@vVLvqOW2Z13Nfbw2SeyNfw4EoS59rJeuk5FgICo1OyFdvSjzg6yGr@HoGfGlIABcs6hoadTmlhjhmNIEydKn/Pl/ylUZ1JgbrH4HwzEePa00EgzxZXprFLsuutWh4agTd0dV5z5lrjXuqUUOop8RaPRjmncJBjfkzUK3fo2anBcba/4OsOw0bIIqz5eiDvfkYecHpegLO1tgf95g5DnWgv4R7Ls7axGB3Iy9sWY@Q4Dxzc5G@fTrjXoA0E4MNM/jbqKagHQWQDH64x2ngWMnwZtQwJt/cAZKNPPfxKohSOgG6546HpnNvpZTqzCtUiUo6otqgxwr40BI0gRPCpCmO1TsscbRuXsFpDp@aShYZAafO5b0gy3cLHyCqYzd62clcEJLHlUgfclkIAnAVF095Dm0W505d5rIh88UcIvlISBFnTi6KrNnBlnWdrO/SOyLjMq1qcVs0JPvsfgE4J8RlotjShG4wDc2uOrxMb4vnNJcPkyotMrGZTO08ejxUJJLvYxFJ2wZdcB9P1dSpRCnShkhw9mlzvyMVQFtfX5e6qYZgHzQqn5q6qYi055PfP39N5vZeOzlbjfr@6C7Y0nX/AA)

All of the versions are on github with the full commit history of golf optimizations:

[regex for matching Fibonacci numbers - short, speed 0.txt](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexGolf/blob/master/regex%20for%20matching%20Fibonacci%20numbers%20-%20short%2C%20speed%200.txt) (the shortest but slowest one, as in this post)
[regex for matching Fibonacci numbers - short, speed 1.txt](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexGolf/blob/master/regex%20for%20matching%20Fibonacci%20numbers%20-%20short%2C%20speed%201.txt)
[regex for matching Fibonacci numbers - short, speed 2.txt](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexGolf/blob/master/regex%20for%20matching%20Fibonacci%20numbers%20-%20short%2C%20speed%202.txt)
[regex for matching Fibonacci numbers - short, speed 3.txt](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexGolf/blob/master/regex%20for%20matching%20Fibonacci%20numbers%20-%20short%2C%20speed%203.txt)
[regex for matching Fibonacci numbers - fastest.txt](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexGolf/blob/master/regex%20for%20matching%20Fibonacci%20numbers%20-%20fastest.txt)
[regex for matching Fibonacci numbers - return index.txt](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexGolf/blob/master/regex%20for%20matching%20Fibonacci%20numbers%20-%20return%20index.txt)

Comment: Amazing! At first, I didn't even know that regular expressions could do math!

Answer (score 18):

### JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```
f=(n,x=0,y=1)=>x<n?f(n,y,x+y):x==n
```

Recursively generates the Fibonacci sequence until it finds an item greater than or equal to the input, then returns item == input.

Comment: NB: naive recursive calculation of the Fibonacci sequence is O(Fib(n)) - approximately O(1.6 ^ n)

Answer (score 13):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 23 bytes

```
^$|^(^1|(?>\2?)(\1))*1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dco7DoAgEAXA/p0DkwUTw1vw18hFCNHCwsbCWHp3pJ3Mc77XfdRO9qGHcbWYr0jhJ2nLmqxkWutoavUgFAERIybMWLCCDQkqGMAI9dCW9Ac)

Input in unary, outputs `0` or `1`.

#### Explanation

The Fibonacci sequence is a good candidate for a solution with forward references, i.e. a "backreference" that refers either to a surrounding group or one that appears later in the regex (in this case, we're actually using both of those). When matching numbers like this, we need to figure out a recursive expression for the *difference* between sequence elements. E.g. to match triangular numbers, we usually match the previous segment plus one. To match square numbers (whose differences are the odd numbers), we match the previous segment plus two.

Since we obtain the Fibonacci numbers by adding the second-to-last element to the last one, the differences between them are also just the Fibonacci numbers. So we need to match each segment as the sum of the previous two. The core of the regex is this:

```
(         # This is group 1 which is repeated 0 or more times. On each
          # iteration it matches one Fibonacci number.
  ^1      # On the first iteration, we simply match 1 as the base case.
|         # Afterwards, the ^ can no longer match so the second alternative
          # is used.
  (?>\2?) # If possible, match group 2. This ends up being the Fibonacci
          # number before the last. The reason we need to make this optional
          # is that this group isn't defined yet on the second iteration.
          # The reason we wrap it in an atomic group is to prevent backtracking:
          # if group 2 exists, we *have* to include it in the match, otherwise
          # we would allow smaller increments.
  (\1)    # Finally, match the previous Fibonacci number and store it in
          # group 2 so that it becomes the second-to-last Fibonacci number
          # in the next iteration.
)*
```

Now this ends up adding the Fibonacci numbers starting at **1**, i.e. **1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...**. Those add up to **1, 2, 4, 7, 12, ...**. I.e. they are one less than the Fibonacci numbers, so we add a `1` at the end. The only case this doesn't cover is zero, so we have the `^$` alternative at the beginning to cover that.

Comment: Very elegant! I'd just like to point out, for completeness's sake, that it can be shortened to 20 bytes in PCRE using a possessive quantifier: `^$|^(^1|\2?+(\1))*1$`

Comment: @Deadcode I do miss those a lot in .NET ;)

Comment: Save 1 byte by removing the unnecessary second `^`.

Comment: @Neil That doesn't work because then it would match the `1` at the end of every non-Fibonacci number by doing zero iterations of the loop.

Comment: Ah, yes, and the fix for that ends up costing that byte. Oh well.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda n:0in((5*n*n+4)**.5%1,abs(5*n*n-4)**.5%1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nci9DkAwFAbQmae4i6Stn1SwSLyJ5UqVJnykunj6kojxnPMO64EmWhpojBvvk2FCrx2E6BQU8lYqVXVZXfB0fVX@JaM9PIEcyDOWWdRaa9mniRWQxDB0eofwIj4)

Comment: Being Python should it not work, given enough resources, for arbitrarily large inputs?

Comment: I always had the impression we could use whatever algorithm we wanted as long, as it works in practice if the calculations fits in the data type and in theory given infinite precision. Sure, using only `int` would set the bar higher (still not arbitrarily large), but we also don't force C answers to use 64-bit integers (or 128-bit with gcc). At any rate, being allowed to use the same algorithm in one language but not another seems nonsensical.

Comment: The algorithmic view does make sense (I had always thought it was the input domain that dictated the "fit in data type" criteria). The only thing to watch for is the grey area between what is the *idea* of the algorithm and its implementation. Here one *could* check if either of the integers are square without casting to floats. I guess that an internal cast as a side-effect is acceptable so long as it is part of a legitimate, working algorithm (...and I'm pretty sure an algorithm that *relied* on the cast would not be acceptable).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Since the maximum value to handle is 1e9, I dont think arbitrarily large inputs would be a problem.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam yes, that detail was actually changed after my comment was made.

Comment: @JonathanAllan nevermind then :)

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <s>48</s> 44 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a=0,b=1:n>a and f(n,b,a+b)or n==a
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##DcnBCoAgDADQ@75iRyUPzeoSrH@ZWCTUEjGir7fe9eW37pf61jY@5AxRUJ1w7wLTrIugaMTNqAtOumCvgsos7dnTsSLNuSSt/yfNdzXWth4IPAwwwgTkgYYP)

<sub>*Thanks to Jonathan Allan for saving 4 bytes*</sub>

Comment: This can be 47 bytes, if truthy values can be `False` and falsy values `True`: [TIO!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1EnydZAx5ArzzYzr6C0REOTqzwjMydVIc8u0Qokl6STqJ3EVVCUmVeikGeT@P@/CQA)

Comment: Could also use `n-a` in place of `n==a` and have -1 and 0 as your return values.

Comment: @carusocomputing I had that in my edit history, but it doesn't work, because for larger test values, you might have `-101` or some other result instead of `-1`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder do you really think that saving 1 byte is worth everybody's sanity?

Comment: @frarugi87 Saving a byte is **always** worth it

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/34718

Comment: @mbomb007 as long as you specify what is thruthy and what is falsy, it's ok.

Comment: That's not the consensus.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
>ÅF¹å¹m
```

Explanation:

```
>ÅF       # Generate Fibbonacci numbers up to n+1
   ¹å     # 0 if original isn't in the list, 1 if it is
     ¹m   # 0**0 = 1 if input was 0 (hotfix for 0).
          # or 0**n if not fibb / 1**n if it is a fibb.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f7nCr26Gdh5ce2pn7/78hAA)

-1 thanks to Jonathan Allan for the 0-not-a-fibonacci-number workaround.

Comment: Actually, won't be updating to 6 bytes. Can't believe there's NO way to append a 0 to a list in under 3 bytes.

Comment: @JonathanAllan the "generate fibbonacci function" in 05AB1E doesn't contain 0.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I understand now, nice idea. Took me a minute to figure out what was actually happening there.

Comment: Isn't it enough to generate upto `n` (saving a byte) as `ÅF` is inclusive and `¹å` would result in `0` either way for `n=0`?

Comment: 0AF = []. 1AF = [1,1]. So apparently not.

Comment: `¹å` on `[]` produces `0` (which is what you want in this case).

Comment: @Emigna actually 0 should return 1, I tried for like 15 minutes to get this below 8 bytes lol.

Comment: Yes, and 0 does return 1 of you remove `>` as `0**0 = 1`

Comment: Where did you find the command `Å`?

Comment: @LordColus https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/extended-math.txt

Comment: Thank you! I haven’t looked much at that page. I’ve only had the main command list open.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8 7</s>  6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
-r‘ÆḞċ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1@36FHDjMNtD3fMO9L9//9/Q2MA)**

#### How?

```
-r‘ÆḞċ - Link: non negative number, n
-      - literal -1      = -1
 r     - inclusive range = [-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,...,n]
  ‘    - increment n     = [ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...,n+1]
   ÆḞ  - Fibonacci       = [ 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,...,fib(n+1)]
     ċ - count occurrences of n (1 if n is a Fibonacci number, 0 otherwise)
```

Notes:

- the increment, `‘`, is needed so this works for **2** and **3**, since they are the **3<sup>rd</sup>** and **4<sup>th</sup>** Fibonacci numbers - beyond **3** all Fibonacci numbers are greater than their index.
- the `-` is needed (rather than just `‘R`) so this works for **0** since **0** is the **0<sup>th</sup>** Fibonacci number;

Comment: Umm, this looks too much like my answer...

Comment: Oh, I golfed mine down to yours, except mine works for `3` :)

Comment: Oh whoops...Fibonacci is weird. (btw deleted my answer then if u say so)

Comment: Are you sure about that last note? When I run the Fibonacci atom on a list starting from 0, 0 is included in the output.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be relevant based on the wording of the challenge, but if you use the count atom with 1 as your argument on the list of Fibonacci numbers the result is 2 (not 1).

Comment: @Christian (weird no notification) yeah you're right it's the zeroth, which means it can be `0r‘`, I dont think I can save a byte from that fact though...

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman yeah 2 is truthy :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan I think you're right. There's an atom that generates a range that starts from zero, but it only goes to n-1, which is too small for this, even with the increment (going from 0 to n). I've been trying to find a one byte atom that can make a number bigger than that, but they're all either not big enough (e.g., increment) or don't work on 0 (e.g., double). If there were an "increment by 10" atom or something like that, that would be perfect...

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 23 bytes

```
{$_∈(0,1,*+*...*>$_)}
```

Comment: `{(0,1,*+*...^*>$_).tail==$_}` was what I was going to initially post. I may have gotten around to [Set operators](https://docs.perl6.org/language/setbagmix) eventually.

Answer (score 5):

## [Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/tree/v1), 3 bytes

```
,fu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K04tyswvLc6p/P9fJ630/39jAA)

Returns the index +1 in the list of Fibonacci numbers if truthy, otherwise returns falsy.

**Explanation:**

```
,fu
,   read input
 f  0-indexed index of that number in the fibonacci sequence (-1 if not in the sequence)
  u increment. (Makes the -1 value falsy and the 0-value truthy)
```

Comment: Seriously rude ^^

Answer (score 5):

## ZX81 BASIC <strike>180</strike> <strike>151</strike> <strike>100</strike> ~94 tokenized BASIC bytes

With thanks to Moggy on the SinclairZXWorld forums, here is a much neater solution that saves more bytes.

```
 1 INPUT I
 2 FOR F=NOT PI TO VAL "1E9"
 3 LET R=INT (VAL ".5"+(((SQR VAL "5"+SGN PI)/VAL "2")**I)/SQR VAL "5")
 4 IF R>=I THEN PRINT F=R
 5 IF R<I THEN NEXT F
```

This will output 1 if a Fibonacci number is entered, or zero if not. Although this saves bytes, it's much slower than the old solutions below. For speed (but more BASIC bytes) remove the `VAL` wrappers around the string literal numbers. Here is the old(er) solutions with some explanations:

```
 1 INPUT A$
 2 LET A=SGN PI
 3 LET B=A
 4 LET F=VAL A$
 5 IF F>SGN PI THEN FOR I=NOT PI TO VAL "1E9"
 6 LET C=A+B
 7 LET A=B
 8 LET B=C
 9 IF B>=F THEN GOTO CODE "£"
10 IF F THEN NEXT I
12 PRINT STR$(SGN PI*(B=F OR F<=SGN PI)) AND F>=NOT PI;"0" AND F<NOT PI
```

The amendments above saves further BASIC bytes to condensing the `IF` statements into a single `PRINT` in line 12; other bytes were saved by using the `VAL` keyword and, and using `GOTO CODE "£"`, which in the ZX81 character set is 12. Strings save more bytes over numbers as all numeric values are stored as floats so therefore take more space on the VAR stack.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I could save another 6 tokenized BASIC bytes by removing line 6 altogether and changing line 5 to `5 IF R<F THEN NEXT I` - my bad!

Answer (score 4):

### C#, 109 bytes

```
bool f(int n){int[]i=new[]{0,1,0};while(i[0]<n||i[1]<n){i[i[2]%2]=i[0]+i[1];i[2]++;}return n==i[0]||n==i[1];}
```

Definitely could be improved, but I didn't have time.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: I wrote my own answer only to realize that it was the same as yours. You can use lambda expressions and simple variables to get this: `n=>{int a=0,b=1,c=0;while(a<n&b<n)if(++c%2>0)a=a+b;else b=a+b;return a==n|b==n;}` (just 80 bytes). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY4xT8MwEIX3/AovIFsJVVrUyXEWpC4tCwzMZ/ciTjJnKXapqra/PSRBAgaE8BueTnffvTsX71zocRCjnIcYxYZsYHCOiql3nn1STJDIifdAe/EIxFJ9jb6hSc@nmPBtsTmwa4hTZUPwreiEEQOb9jy2BJi6smZZOVPr4yt5lNDwrW1YUSfL0t2s2lqBgdJq9BGFncse06HncdnwxY6mr4Mufjv9EDgGj4uXnhLuiFF2slZK/5dd5rBZ8H0OvM6AVzlvrOfkv@gnhP0WT/JH5rX49OED)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Save a further 2 bytes on that with `a+=b` instead of `a=a+b` and `b+=a` instead of `b=a+b`.

Comment: -1 bytes: replace `int[]i` with `var i`

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>21</s> 19+3 = <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
i1\{=n;
?!\:@+:{:}(
```

Input is expected to be on the stack at program start, so +3 bytes for the `-v` flag.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9Mwpto2z5rLXjHGykHbqtqqVuP///@6ZQqGppbmAA)

This works by generating Fibonacci numbers until they are greater than or equal to the input number, then checking the last generated number for equality with the input. Outputs `1` if it was a Fibonacci number, `0` otherwise.

To ensure that `0` is handled correctly, the seed is `-1 1` - the first number generated will be `0` rather than `1`.

Thanks to @cole for pointing out that `i` can be used to push `-1` onto the stack when STDIN is empty. Very clever!

Previous version:

```
01-1\{=n;
}(?!\:@+:{:
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid for wasting bytes continuously checking each generated number along the way. Nicely done!

Comment: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P9Mwpto2z5rLXjHGykHbqtqqVuP///@6ZQqGppbmAA) using `i` instead of `01-`.

Comment: @cole of course, using `i` as `-1` when there is no input to STDIN, I'd not considered that. Nicely done!

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 37 bytes

```
!Fibonacci@n~Table~{n,0,#+1}~FreeQ~#&
```

*-4 bytes from @ngenisis*

Comment: `Fibonacci[0]` gives `0`, so you can save `4` bytes by including `0` in the `Table` range. You can save another byte using infix notation for `Table`: `!Fibonacci@n~Table~{n,0,#+1}~FreeQ~#&`

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 32 bytes

```
n->!prod(x=0,n+1,fibonacci(x)-n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYqxDcAgDMBeSTsRlUhwAPxCqVKxhCjqwPc0gz1Y1maDXt0MBbZQPdTmE1ZJUa4cedxTWu8jLCTBzdOC@JkiZEdtyOfhBKouDoKI@wc)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 44 bytes

```php
for(;0>$s=$x-$argn;)$x=+$y+$y=$x?:1;echo!$s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwJVaVJRfFF@UWpBfVJKZl65R5xrv5x/i6eyqac2lkliUnmdrbGL9Py2/SMPawE6l2FalQhcsbK2pUmGrrVIJREAxeytD69TkjHxFlWLr//@/5uXrJicmZ6QCAA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 58 bytes

```php
for($x=0,$y=1;$x<$argn;$x=$y,$y=$t)$t=$x+$y;echo$x==$argn;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwJVaVJRfFF@UWpBfVJKZl65R5xrv5x/i6eyqac2lkliUnmdrbGL9Py2/SEOlwtZAR6XS1tBapcIGLAVk2KpUgsRUSjRVSmxVKrRVKq1TkzPygRK2ECX//3/Ny9dNTkzOSAUA)

Comment: Golfed more: `for(;0>$s=$x-$argn;)$x=+$y+$y=$x?:1;echo!$s;`.

Comment: @user63956 Thank You for the learning effort with the chaining variables assignment

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, 17 bytes

```
0∊1|.5*⍨4 ¯4+5××⍨
```

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u236A%28%u22A2%2C0%u220A1%7C0.5*%u23684%20%AF4+5%D7%D7%u2368%29%20%A8%u237325&run)

Answer (score 3):

## MATL (16 bytes)

```
2^5*4-t8+hX^tk=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yjOVMtEt8RCOyMiriTbtvj/f0Pjr3n5usmJyRmpAA)

Not the golfiest solution, but wanted to use the direct method of [checking if "5*x^2+/-4" is a perfect square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Recognizing_Fibonacci_numbers).

### Explanation:

```
2^5*    % 5 times the input squared
4-      % push the above minus 4
t8+     % push the above plus 8 (+4 overall)
hX^     % concatenate them into an array and then take the sqrt().
tk      % push a copy of the array that is rounded using floor().
=       % test if the sqrt's were already integers
s       % sum the results, returns 0 if neither was a perfect square.
```

### Note:

In the "0" case it returns "2" because both 4 and -4 are perfect squares, same with 1 which produces "1 1". Consider any non-zero output as "truthy", and 0 as "falsy".

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 37 bytes

```java
s->s.matches(".?|(\\2?+(\\1|^.))*..")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZAxb9swEIV3/4qDAANScqZFkY6tunWADt7aJd3qNKBlKaYrkYJIBTUa/3b3bCkZknjr8Egcv8Px3dupJzXabX4fdVXbxsOOatZ6XbKiNZnX1rCr@SArlXPwTWnzdwBQt@tSZ@C88nQ9Wb2BilB45xttHn/eg2oeXQSnVoBlP@ZzRxG@WlvmyiyggC9wdKOFY5Xy2TZ3YcBun8PVKrm9ppM//2JRdMVYEB1Pg@aD87y7vfN5xWzrWU0DfWnC4EfT@u0@iObnDnokD4VeW6OyTH9vq3XeOPqsMwQQI8cEBU5whlxgwlFInFCVYt@R3ExTLpP0BmE8BimaTQ@kEDKVUkw7IP22B@PxNOYynk2F6NCkR4fOVGEbCMkZmE/vrEWvzt4uV4TBkCcbGC1g6IYmQDAIBVN1Xe7D4E/AmrzOlQ9NFPXLHy6ntFSlexOSsWZ5OSeJQAHQqikCj0mclJAI8AmJKCfMZyTqSeKX/E55pGn60AtfQ@IPcRy/6FI@H7j6vxGddDj@Aw)

This works for numbers up to 1,836,311,903 (47th fibonacci number) included. Above that, the result is undefined (including a potential infinite loop).

### Credits

- Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen and David Conrad for helping golfing :)
- Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen for porting the regex version, saving 12 bytes in the process!

Comment: Nice approach. Btw, you can golf a byte by changing `n==0` to `n<1`. In the question it states "_A non-negative integer between 0 and 1,000,000,000_".

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I golfed not 1, but 5 bytes with that clause! :-P Thanks, I hadn't noticed it.

Comment: You don't need a temp variable for the Fibonacci sequence. You can calculate successive pairs with `b+=a;a=b-a;`

Comment: You're doing black magic, @DavidConrad! I'm telling you! Black magic! :)

Comment: 37 bytes by taking input as unary and porting the Retina approach: [`s->s.matches(".?|(\\2?+(\\1|^.))*..")`](https://tinyurl.com/yany3x7k) ([Here an explanation of that regex.](https://pastebin.com/QQULqT90))

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 51 bytes

```cs
bool f(int n,int a=0,int b=1)=>a<n?f(n,b,a+b):a==n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5NS8NAFLz3Vwylhw2@hsTUfli3HrwqFDz0UHrYxE19EN@W7KJI2N8e03jpZd7wZpiZys8r19q@aoz32KOb@GACV/h2/IE3w6J8aFnOxxNMe/bJ4MDgu0BD7A/2KtkOj3rIMNWnYglgsFy146nLCDnhnlAQFoQHwpKwIqwJm0HKi8UmK/LlDV9lNzyP/3XA@68P9it9ceJdY9NDy8G@slg1m3YcMd@hu6S14iROxz1xEvvSuQb1OEnoikZn4y11nuideZLnWgmVZO7K5NFoLds@9n8)

-6 bytes thanks to @Oliver!

This solution uses a pretty straightforward recursive function.

- The variable `n` is the number to be tested.
- The variables `a` and `b` are the 2 most recent numbers in the sequence.
- Checks if the first of the 2 most recent number is less than input. When this is the case, a recursive call is made to the next numbers in the series.
- Otherwise, check whether the first number is equal to input and return the result.

The TIO link demonstrates this working for 1134903170 which exceeds the maximum value required by the challenge.

Comment: It's nice to see C# solutions lately :) -  I think you can simply check if `a<n` for [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU5NS8NAFLz3Vwylhw2@hsTUfli3HrwqFDz0UHrYxE19EN@W7KJI2N8e03jpZd7wZpiZys8r19q@aoz32KOb@GACV/h2/IE3w6J8aFnOxxNMe/bJ4MDgu0BD7A/2KtkOj3rIMNWnYglgsFy146nLCDnhnlAQFoQHwpKwIqwJm0HKi8UmK/LlDV9lNzyP/3XA@68P9it9ceJdY9NDy8G@slg1m3YcMd@hu6S14iROxz1xEvvSuQb1OEnoikZn4y11nuideZLnWgmVZO7K5NFoLds@9n8)

Comment: Thanks! And nice tip :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), <s>205</s> 134 bytes

<sup>Big thanks to [ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39244/ascii-only) for rather clever merging of states, saving 71 bytes!!</sup>

```bash
_->In_x+c+u
u+b->u+a+d
u+0b->v
v+c->v+b+d
v+0c->w
w+a+x->w+y
w+0a+0x->Out_"1"
w+a+0x->Out_"0"
w+0a+x+y->w+2x
w+0a+0y+d->w+c
w+0d+0a->u
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PY0xDsMgDEV3jsH6heQke/ZOPQIiUCmV2i4JBE7vftook9@zn@Twiuvj/dx2Ve/m28dXRGSTsbg5IyARhVxMQeTAwlWBkA9zMKgENKIECOWed28H@7tdLvYfVLSej/XsG1L32DVxw5@q4zSpS8MX) or [verify in batch!](https://tio.run/##TY3BasMwEETv@opBiJCwpFF6K8E@BnrqB4RgZMnFhlRqLMuxof@urptQcto3s7OztYltztYMKNHFY1eHF9t78Rl6eHQeah2bKzTUfnOACwLom5guQyHVurFtgPL4wS58DztzsW3z1cUneqrcSL49nSDVvUCiKCD3EuczVis8uoQLvsm52pbvvprIUhKJ6m2ZyJBj1MyjGMnyoJqtkTTzTdw4MDHQzKgNaRYfaaj4w9/uX2t5D0w0L/HX6ZGfyS3aLtKxwz/zm/4F)

### Ungolfed

```bash
# read input, initialize (c = 1)
_ -> In_x + c + s0

# a,d <- b
s0 +  b -> s0 + a + d
s0 + 0b -> s1

# b,d <- c
s1 +  c -> s1 + b + d
s1 + 0c -> s2

s2 +  a +  x -> s2 + y            # y <- min(a,x)
s2 + 0a + 0x -> Out_"1"           # if (a == x): was Fibonacci
s2 +  a + 0x -> Out_"0"           # if (a >  x): stop (we exceeded target)
s2 + 0a +  x +  y -> s2 + 2x      # if (a <  x): x += a (since y = a) / restore x
s2 + 0a      + 0y +  d -> s2 + c  # once that's done; c <- d
s2 + 0a           + 0d->s0        # and finally loop
```

Comment: Wip: https://tio.run/##JcpBCsMgFATQvcfIdhCsB8i@qx5BjD/QQNVALOjla@e3i8@8YX58peeej6vNGex6L6FjQ0I2GZtdMyKEdHQxBYnBXUhHV1P50AkM0kU4lse7heW2/Dbt/4U40Q0PQ@nVbkC0JLUg0ipmntN/6tmOWq5pxX8B

Comment: [139](https://tio.run/##Nc3NCsMgEATgu4@R6yDY5p57T30EMW4hgfgDsaAvXzO29LTf7CysO/z2CvtZerd6eURbscIjqIBVLwEOQho6qgjPwV5IQyeVeFAJNNI4GIbnu9jpNn27kX8NkVFVRvvDNMiwpx0xVsJTvu39Ps@flMue4tm1XA). you can remove some `0` checks for fewer bytes at the cost of nondeterminism

Comment: [129](https://tio.run/##LY3BCsMgEETvfkaug2CTe@499RPEuIUGqhZiQX@@m7Htad@bGdjwjI972o@q6u16zb5hQ0QyCZtdEwKE6MjZZEQe9kJ05GIKB42ATnQBjnJ7Vz9dpm83/Nc09LGb23/YIcPjUGHCZ6rzsnzKq@4lH2rlBA)

Comment: @ASCII-only: That's pretty nice! Fails for 0 though, but not adding the `b`-atom on initialization fixes it (and saves 2 bytes) :D Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 4 bytes

```
ÞFce
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiyoAobuKCtGAgPT4gYOKCtG7OuyIsIsOeRmNlIiwiO+KAoCwpIiwiMTUwIl0=) - show all boolean results
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiyoAobs67Iiwiw55GY2UiLCI74oCgW24sXSkiLCI0MjAwIl0=) - show only numbers returning truthy

Thanks to Steffan. This based on the alternative 5 byte answer below, removing the need for the `$`.

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ÞF0pc
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLKgChu4oK0YCA9PiBg4oK0bs67Iiwiw55GMHBjIiwiO+KAoCwpIiwiMTUwIl0=) - show all boolean results
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLKgChuzrsiLCLDnkYwcGMiLCI74oCgW24sXSkiLCIxNjAwIl0=) - show only numbers returning truthy

```
ÞF   # All 1-indexed Fibonacci numbers as a LazyList.
0p   # Prepend the list with 0
c    # Is the input contained in the list?
```

Alternative 5 bytes:

```
ÞFc$e
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLKgChu4oK0YCA9PiBg4oK0bs67Iiwiw55GYyRlIiwiO+KAoCwpIiwiMTUwIl0=) - show all boolean results
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLKgChuzrsiLCLDnkZjJGUiLCI74oCgW24sXSkiLCI0MjAwIl0=) - show only numbers returning truthy

```
ÞF   # All 1-indexed Fibonacci numbers as a LazyList.
c    # Is the input contained in the list?
$    # Swap above result with the input (this creates a copy of the input)
e    # Exponentiate. For an input of zero this will yield 0**0 == 1; for other
     # Fibonacci numbers, 1**{n>0} == 1; otherwise 0**{n>0} == 0.
```

The above two solutions work around the fact that there's no 0-indexed version of `ÞF`. Alternatively using `∆F` requires a different workaround, but it can also be done in 5 bytes:

```
Þn∆Fc
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLKgChu4oK0YCA9PiBg4oK0bs67Iiwiw55u4oiGRmMiLCI74oCgLCkiLCIxNTAiXQ==) - show all boolean results
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLKgChuzrsiLCLDnm7iiIZGYyIsIjvigKBbbixdKSIsIjE2MDAiXQ==) - show only numbers returning truthy

```
Þn  # All integers in an infinite list (0, 1, -1, 2, -2, ...)
∆F  # nth Fibonacci number, 0-indexed
c   # Contains - Check if one thing contains another
```

Using `ʀ` (Inclusive range [0..input]) instead of `Þn` wouldn't work, because the Fibonacci numbers \$2\$ and \$3\$ are not members of the lists \$[0,1,1]\$ and \$[0,1,1,2]\$ respectively. It would be necessary to use `›ʀ` (the range [0..input+1]), but for non-Fibonacci numbers that is exponentially slower than using `Þn` (and `Þn∆Fc` is in turn a bit slower than `ÞFc$e`).

Note that `Þn` includes negative numbers, and `∆F` on a negative number returns a negative Fibonacci number. However, `Þn∆Fc` only returns truthy for nonnegative Fibonacci numbers, probably due to a bug in Vyxal.

---

Without using any Fibonacci builtins (**7 bytes**):

```
k≈⁽+dḞc
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLKgChu4oK0YCA9PiBg4oK0bs67Iiwia+KJiOKBvStk4bieYyIsIjvigKAsKSIsIjE1MCJd) - show all boolean results
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLKgChuzrsiLCJr4omI4oG9K2ThuJ5jIiwiO+KAoFtuLF0pIiwiMTYwMCJd) - show only numbers returning truthy

The is based on [lyxal's answer to Fibonacci function or sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223094/17216).

```
k≈   # the list [0, 1]
⁽+d  # lambda x, y: x + y
Ḟ    # Create an infinite sequence based on the function and the initial list.
c    # Does the list contain the input?
```

Comment: 5-byte workaround, just use `v`: `ʀv∆Fc`

Comment: @Steffan Interesting. That is a direct workaround to the bug using knowledge of its nature. I also found another 5 byte workaround (above).

Comment: [4 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiyoAobs67Iiwiw55GY2UiLCI74oCgW24sXSkiLCI0MjAwIl0=) with `r` flag.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ȷḶÆḞi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///E9oc7th1ue7hjXub///8NAQ)

Returns 0 for non-Fibonacci numbers, and the 1-indexed position of the number in the Fibonacci sequence for Fibonacci numbers.

Explanation:

```
ȷḶÆḞi
ȷ        The literal number 1000
 Ḷ       Range [0,1,...,999]
  ÆḞ     Get the ith Fib number; vectorizes [1,1,2,3,5,...,<1000th Fib number>]
    i    Get the first index of element in list, or 0 if not found
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```
pryr::f(x%in%DescTools::Fibonacci(0:45))
```

`pryr::f` creates a function:

```
function (x) 
x %in% DescTools::Fibonacci(0:45)
```

Uses `DescTools::Fibonacci` to create the first `x+1` fibonacci numbers and checks for inclusion. `x+1` because the third fibnum is 2, and that wouldn't be enough to check for inclusion of 3.

Luckily `Desctools::Fibonacci(0)=0`, so that is a nice freebee.

-3 bytes thanks to MickyT

Comment: `-1:x+1` will save you a byte, but `0:45` will save you three and cover the required range

Comment: @MickyT Oh, I must've overlooked the required range specification. Thanks :)

Comment: An alternative approach, only 36 bytes: `pryr::f(any(!(5*n^2+c(-4,4))^.5%%1))`.

Comment: I got it down to 32 bytes, see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126855/59052).

Comment: I'm not so familiar with code golf rules -- does allowing non-base packages  make sense? I could write arbitrary R code into a package, install it, and run it the same way you have run the function from `pryr`.

Comment: @mb7744 Yes you could. But as with all the programming languages, the package should predate the challenge. This is so you couldn't make a package with functions that directly solve the challenge.

Comment: That makes sense, fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.4](http://julialang.org/), 29 bytes

```julia
!m=in(0,sqrt(5*m*m+[4,-4])%1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8r5hr@z8zT8NAp7iwqETDVCtXK1c72kRH1yRWU9VQ839BUWZeiYaioZHmfwA)

---

If this isn't how you do a Julia answer, let me know. I'm unsure of how input works on TIO.

Comment: You'd have to make it a regular function (counting `!m=`) or a lambda (counting `m->`). More importantly, this fails for **0** as is.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

```hs
f=0:scanl(+)1f
(`elem`take 45f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P83WwKo4OTEvR0Nb0zCNK91WIyE1JzU3oSQxO1XBxDRN839uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikJuYoFCukK0gZ6eoUHsfwA) This exploits the fact that the input will be in the range  from 0 to 1,000,000,000, hence we need to check only the first 45 Fibonacci numbers. `f=0:scanl(+)1f` generates an infinite list of Fibonacci numbers, `take 45f` is the list of the first 45 Fibonacci numbers and `elem` checks whether the input is in this list.

---

#### Unrestricted version: 36 bytes

```hs
f=0:scanl(+)1f
g n=n`elem`take(n+3)f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAe6/YQwdFEKVb4EsicInVxHWR9P828@KoxLxWCu4cDworo33aMkiQSEwtTqykxBw6rYZFIED/ikzYoWGHDJez1rt7/Q) For any `n`, taking the first `n+3` Fibonacci numbers will guarantee that `n` will be in this list if it's a Fibonacci number.

Note that this approach is incredible inefficient for high numbers that are not Fibonacci numbers, because all `n+3` Fibonacci numbers need to be computed.

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, <s>61</s> 54 bytes

```
(defun f(x)(do((a 0 b)(b 1(+ a b)))((>= a x)(= a x))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoQwFEOvEgQxHxFs93qXOrUgqF8cB1z16vUzZpMHeeSzLt@jFMY5/XYk3sKoZECPSTjBsUUwFCHHwdCEtyyFq@qBpCduLDsa9nDwcF4QFbRhCxcuVNlHdCNyyHVlLtP/oDw)

The reduction in size with respect to the previous version:

```
(defun f(x)(do((a 0 b)(b 1 c)(c 1(+ b c)))((>= a x)(= a x))))
```

was triggered by the idea that to generate the sequence of the Fibonacci numbers only two variables are necessary, not three.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6 without the ** operator), 44 bytes

```
f=(x,c=x*(Math.sqrt(5)-1)/2%1)=>x*(c-c*c)<.5
```

Relies on the ratio between successive Fibonacci numbers approaching the golden ratio. The value of c is the fractional part of the input divided by the golden ratio - if the input is Fibonacci then this will be very close to 1 and the value of c-c² will be very small.

Not as short as some of the other JS answers but runs in O(1) time.

Comment: Are you sure it is exact?

Comment: Doesn't work for the fibonacchi number 16558014

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>32</s> 31 bytes

Takes input from stdin, returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` as appropriate.

```
any(!(5*scan()^2+-1:1*4)^.5%%1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## D, <strike>98</strike> <strike>79 bytes</strike> 77 bytes

*-19 bytes: changed square number algorithm (which also had the side effect of not needing `import std;`) and realized the non-UFCS way was 1 byte shorter*

golfed:

```
int p(real z){return z^^.5%1==0;}int f(int z){return p(5*z*z+4)||p(5*z*z-4);}
```

readable:

```
int p(real z){
    return z^^.5%1==0
}
int f(int z){
    return p(5*z*z+4)||p(5*z*z-4);
}
```

where `f` is the function that tests if a number is a fibonacci number.

This uses the fact that `a positive integer z is a Fibonacci number if and only if one of 5z^2 + 4 or 5z^2 − 4 is a perfect square.` [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Recognizing_Fibonacci_numbers)

Also `real` instead of `float` for one less byte, and returning an `int` instead of `bool` to save another byte (since ints are truthy if they're nonzero, and D implicitly casts expressions to the function's return value if possible, in this case casting a bool to an int).

There's probably some way to avoid having the extra function `p` (used to check if a number is a perfect square) but I can't find it out.

edit: replaced z^^2 with z*z

Comment: if your `z^^2` means `z^2` you can do `z*z` instead i think

Comment: Presumably just doing the check on both sides of the condition would be shorter than having a whole function? Something like `(5*z*z+4)^^.5%1==0||(5*z*z-4)^^.5%1==0`

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
ÅFå¤¹_~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cKvb4aWHlhzaGV/3/7@hMQA)

Comment: Actually, this randomly seems to return 2, 3 and 4. Try for input of 13 and above.

Comment: `ÅFsåO¹_~` fixes it but thats another byte. feelsbadman

Comment: @Datboi Actually can be fixed still 7 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 33 bytes

```
AtomQ@*InverseFunction[Fibonacci]
```

Comment: You can save a couple of bytes with `@*` (and then drop the final `@#&`)

Answer (score 1):

## JS (ES6), 57 bytes

```
n=>(y=y=>((5*(n**2)+y)**0.5),~~y(4)==y(4)|~~y(-4)==y(-4))
```

Uses [carusocomputing's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126373/am-i-a-fibonacci-number/126397#comment311152_126373). Alot golfier than [my other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126397/70700).

#### Ungolfed

```
n=>{
    y=y=>((5*(n**2)+y)**0.5);//carusocomputing's method in a function
    return ~~y(4) === y(4) || ~~y(-4) === y(-4);//~~x === Math.floor(x)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>76</s>, <s>52</s>, 71 bytes,

### <s>Thanks GPT4 with a bit of prompt engineering</s>

#### Way off, just plain wrong, good for the three test inputs but...

### GTP4 after some serious tutoring finally 58 bytes

```c
f(n,a,b){for(a=b=1;a<n;b+=a,a=b-a);return n==a||n==b||!n;}
```

```c
F(n){return n<2?n:F(n-1)+F(n-2);}i;f(n){for(i=0;F(i)<n;i++);int x=F(i)==n;}
```

```c
f(n,i,j){for(i=0,j=1;j<n;i=j,j+=i);return j==n||!n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/99NI0@zOjOvRKHSNs/GyD7PCiiga6ipDaKMNK1rM63TQCrS8os0rN00MjVt8qwztbU1rUFaKmxBIra2eda1/3MTM/M0NLmquRSAIE3DQNO@oLSkWEMpREnTCsJyU9K0hsoa4pU1witrjFfWFK@sBX5X4bfYEL/NRvg9ZWyCQ7r2PwA)

Comment: [Here is 3 bytes of that solution in the for loop.](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/99NI0@zuii1pLQoTyHPxsg@zwooomuoqQ2ijDStazOt00BK0vKLNKzdNDI1bfKsM7W1Na2hekBCtrZ51rX/cxMz8zQ0uaq5FIAgTcNA076gtKRYQylESdMKwnJT0rSGyhrilTXCrxeXdO1/AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: you need to reset `i=0` if you're going to call it with a lower value, otherwise the function is only guaranteed to work once

Answer (score 1):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>40</s> 83 bytes

Added 43 bytes so that it takes the correct input

```
i:0(?vc4*-
 v&a~<
+>l2(?v$&:a*&*
v   ~&<
>10r:&1)?v1n;
=?v&:&)?v>:{+::&:&
  >1n;n0<
```

A less golfy version would be:

```
// Read input
i:0(?vc4*-
     >~a&v
         >l2(?v$&:a*&*+
              >&~04.
// Determine if in Fibonacci
 10r:&1)?v1n;
         >:{+::&:&=?v&:&)?v
                    >1n;n0<
```

Comment: Finally, a ><> answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>56 63</s>  61 bytes

```
{for(n[++j]++;n[j]<$1;n[++j]=n[j]+n[j-1]){}$0=$0?n[j]==$1:1}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SCMvWls7K1Zb2zovOivWRsXQGiJgC@JqAwldw1jN6loVA1sVA3uQmK2tiqGVYa3h///GhuYWhoYA)

Brute force is fun. :)
If you want it to work for arbitrarily large numbers, add a `-M` argument, but that is outside the scope of the problem.

7 bytes added to account for `0` as input, but shaved a couple off using the ternary operator.

Comment: Umm, this doesn't return truthy for 0, which, according to the question, is included in the Fibonacci Sequence.

Comment: I misread the input, somehow, as saying positive number, rather than non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 37 bytes

```
ri1T{\1$+_3$-g"1T 0_ 1"S/=~}g]W=
```

CJam has no Fibonnaci built-in. On the bright side, this does use `g` twice, and I think this is the first time I've ever used it!

Answer (score 1):

## k, 20 bytes

```
{*x=*|(*x>)(|+\)\1 1}
```

Generates fibonacci numbers until it overshoots. Then it checks the last one it generated for equality. `1` is truthy, `0` is falsey.

[Try it online.](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/?run=%7B%2ax%3D%2a%7C%28%2ax%3E%29%28%7C%2B%5C%29%5C1%201%7D%270%201%202%2012)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 30 bytes

```
Or@@EvenQ[2Sqrt[5#^2+{4,-4}]]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 94 bytes

```
x->{int i=0;for(;c(i++)<=x;);return c(i-2)==x;}int c(int n){return n<1?0:n<2?1:c(n-1)+c(n-2);}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lZLBb4IwFMbv/BUvnmgMCAhGrczbbvPibssOtdYNBy2hxWkMfzsraLbLlseSNk3b3/ve9yXvyE7MU6WQx/1Hy3OmNTyxTF4dgEwaUR0YF7DprgA7pXLBJHDXfsGZUPva2G3XBiSk0J69h2v3l6UBPajKpRYdj8kqPVNCK2Hqqq/2IpLap8ahnSxMJrBRBkpWGVAHMO8CdhcjPK5qaZxO79ZRkutdQ67CdbCUq2gdLrkrvZCMuyMitGl7P2W9yzMO2jBjj5PK9lDYWO7WVJl8e3kFRm6ZurBQWO9SfPYXt4/ViwBsL9qIwle18UtbaHLpjp6rWoAR2rpiWujl6F7wC1v40uduQDAiRIkIJaYokaDEHHeKt4nwNNMYNzvA7QK3G@OdZtMoThbzGS42S5J5EMbf@f4ckUeW6//NyACbuD98SJIBsxjgTDRMJxhIBT9o4zTtFw) (NOTE: It's a bit slow for very large test-cases.)

```
x->{                 // Method (1) with integer parameter and boolean return-type
  int i=0;           //  Index
  for(;c(i++)<=x;);  //  Loop as long as the Fibonacci number is smaller or equal to the input
  return c(i-2)==x;  //  And then return if the input equals the previous Fibonacci number
}                    // End of method (1)

                     // Method to get `n`th Fibonacci number
int c(int n){        // Method (2) with integer parameter and integer return-type
  return n<1?        //  If `n`==0:
    0                //   Return 0
   :n<2?             //  Else if `n`==1
    1                //   Return 1
   :                 //  Else:
    c(n-1)+c(n-2);   //   Return recursive calls with `n-1` and `n-2`
}                    // End of method (2)
```

Comment: +1 for trying the recursive, but [I think the iterative is shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126579/16236) ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 33+3 = 36 bytes

3 bytes added for the -v flag

```
10:{:}=?!v1n;
)?v:@+10.\:{:}
n0/;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39DAqtqq1tZescwwz5pL077MykHb0EAvBiTKlWegb/3//3/dMgVzA0MTAwtzY2MA)

**Or 54 bytes without using the -v flag**

```
 0ic4*-:0(?v$a*+10.
:{:}=?!v1n;\10
v:@+d1.\:{:})?
\0n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8EgM9lES9fKQMO@TCVRS9vQQI/Lqtqq1tZescwwzzrG0ICrzMpBO8VQLwYkrGnPFWOQZ/3/v7mBoYmBhbmxMQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

```
fu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/z@t9P9/CwA)

Pushes either a positive number for truthy or 0 for falsy.

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 22 <s>24</s> bytes

0 is truthy, nothing is falsey

```
@0O1I!^/@.W<rq\?-p+;;u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9/BwN/QUzFO30Ev3KaoMMZet0Db2rr0/39TUwA)

```
    @ 0
    O 1
I ! ^ / @ . W <
r q \ ? - p + ;
    ; u
    . .
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIEAgMAogICAgTyAxCkkgISBeIC8gQCAuIFcgPApyIHEgXCA/IC0gcCArIDsKICAgIDsgdQogICAgLiAuCg==&input=NA==&speed=15)

<s>I may be able to get a couple more out of this</s> ... found them with a change to the initial redirect into the loop

- `I` get the integer to check
- `!` check for 0 input

  - `^O@` if zero, output and halt
- `/01` initialise the stack for doing the sequence
- `W<W` change lane onto the redirect back to self, then change lane into looping section
- `+p-?` bring the check value to the top, subtract and check

  - `/@` On a positive result reflect and halt
  - `\^O@` On a zero result reflect, output and halt
  - `u;\qr;` Remove the check, move check value to bottom, rotate the sum, remove the low value.  Continue into loop.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 40 bytes

```
r->Math.abs((r*Math.sqrt(5)-~r)%2*r-r)<2
```

This is a straight Java port of @xnor's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126524/794).

Answer (score 1):

## [D](http://dlang.org/), 57 bytes

A nice, clean, no-nonsense solution:

```swift
int f(int n,int x=0,int y=1){return y<n?f(n,y,x+y):y==n;}
```

---

This one is 58 bytes but doesn't use recursion, and so might be more practical for larger inputs:

```swift
alias f=(n){int x,y=1;for(;y<n;y+=x,x=y-x){}return y==n;};
```

---

And here's one where the function declaration itself is only 54 bytes, though it depends on the [mach](https://github.com/pineapplemachine/mach.d) library.

```swift
import mach.range : r=recur, l=last;
import mach.math.vector : v=vector;
const z=v(0,1);

// The 54-byte function
alias f=n=>z.r!(a=>v(a.y,a.x+a.y),a=>a.y>n).l(z).y==n;

// Exploded for readability
alias f=n=>(
    vector(0,1) // Seed the sequence
        .recur!(v=>vector(v.y,v.x+v.y),v=>v.y>n) // Compute Fib numbers until N
        .last(vector(0,1)).y == n // If the last number was N, return true
        // Value in parens "last(...)" is a fallback for n==0 and empty seq.
);
```

---

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
ÆMgXÃøU
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=xk1nWMP4VQ==&input=MTI=)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
Æ   Ã
```

Generate an array of integers from 0 to `U-1` and pass each through a function where `X` is the current element.

```
MgX
```

Get the `X`th Fibonacci number.

```
øU
```

Check if the array contains (`ø`) the original input `U`. Implicitly return the boolean result.

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 8 bytes

```
=0,1?Z+Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39ZAx9A@Sjvy/38DAA)

### Explanation

```
=0,1        Set sequence start to 0,1
    ?       Mode: Query (assumes increasing sequences)
     Z+Y    Each item is the previous two summed
```

Answer (score 1):

#### C, 36 bytes

```
f(x,a,b){return x>b?f(x,b,a+b):x==b}
```

It puts some warnings, and requires at least 32-bit integers. Newer C standards probably won't even compile it. It should be called as `f(142857,0,1)`.

Bonus: it can calculate Fibonacci-ness with different initial values, too.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>64 41</s> 40 bytes

```ruby
->n,a=b=1{a,b=b,a+b;a<n ?redo:a>n ?p: 1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcY9EsIgEAbQq3yDjRmRgbGLkhxELXYV4jYxk5/CAc6OedWbN/7VwT/quRs1efYukWbPmk58pduIfg7vb0vdvqmFK/VojbnYxgR6fZCyZEzbukAdkhTIAkIUVpCI4S7PUv8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
1;0⟨t≡+⟩ⁱhℕ↙.!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX133qG3Do6bmRx3LlUqKSlP1lPQedaxQSkvMKQayax/u6qx9uHXCf0Nrg0fzV5Q86lyo/Wj@ykeNGzMetUx91DZTT/H//2gDHUMdIx1DIx1jHVMdCx1zHUsdY3NzHRMjAx0DQ0MLS0tLCwtDIGloaGluZGocCwA)

Takes input through the output variable and outputs through success or failure, and in the case of success the input variable is unified with 1.

```
1;0               Starting with [1,0],
        ⁱ         iterating
   ⟨ ≡ ⟩          replacing
   ⟨t  ⟩          the first element of the pair with the last element
   ⟨  +⟩          and the last element with the sum of the pair
         h        until the first element
          ℕ↙      is greater than or equal to
            .     the output variable,
             !    and stopping then,
         h        the first element of the pair is equal to the output variable.
```

`ℕ↙.!` is necessary for it to terminate on false test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## k4, <s>30</s> 26 bytes

-4 thanks to ngn!

```
{x in(x>*|:){x,+/-2#x}/!2}
```

---

the above is a simple while iterator. `(cond){func}/arg`.

```
            {x,+/-2#x}           / x join sum over last 2 elements of x (i.e. append next Fib)
     (x>*|:)          /!2        / while outer func input is greater than last element (x>*|:) of inner func output, pass inner func output to inner func
 x in                            / check if x is in array. returns boolean
```

Comment: `last@` -> `*|:`, `0 1` -> `!2`

Comment: @ngn thanks, updated!

Comment: would it still work if you moved the first arg to the left of `{` `}/`? `{x,+/-2#x}/[x>*|:;!2]` -> `(x>*|:){x,+/-2#x}/!2`

Comment: yeah it does. that was my first approach but i couldn't get it to work. not sure what's different now. thanks again, will update!

Answer (score 1):

## [CSASM v2.1.2.3](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.1.2.3), 259 bytes

```
func main:
push 0
pop $1
push 1
pop $2
in ""
conv i32
pop $a
push $a
push 1
comp.lte
push $f.o
brfalse c
.lbl b
push 1
print
ret
.lbl a
push 0
print
ret
.lbl c
clf.o
push $1
dup
push $2
add
pop $1
pop $2
push $1
push $a
comp.gt
push $f.o
brtrue a    
push $1
push $a
comp
push $f.o
brtrue b
br c
ret
end
```

**Commented and ungolfed:**

```
func main:
    ; Seed the sequence ($1 = new value, $2 = old value)
    push 0
    pop $1
    push 1
    pop $2

    ; Get the input, convert it to an integer and store it in the accumulator
    in ""
    conv i32
    pop $a

    ; If $a <= 1, print truthy (1)
    push $a
    push 1
    comp.lte
    push $f.o
    brfalse loop

.lbl isFib
    ; Print a truthy value
    push 1
    print
    ret
.lbl notFib
    ; Print a falsy value
    push 0
    print
    ret

    ; Keep generating new Fibonacci numbers until $1 is >= $a
    .lbl loop
        ; Clear the Comparison flag
        clf.o
        
        ; Get the next Fibonacci pair:
        ; $2 = $1, $1 = $1 + $2
        push $1
        dup
        push $2
        add
        pop $1
        pop $2

        ; If $1 > $a, the input wasn't a Fibonacci number
        push $1
        push $a
        comp.gt
        push $f.o
        brtrue notFib
        
        ; If $1 == $a, the input was a Fibonacci number
        push $1
        push $a
        comp
        push $f.o
        brtrue isFib

        ; Still need to generate more numbers
        br loop
    ret
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 34 bytes

```
d0r^+0 1[d3R+d4Rd_5R>s]dssx0r4R-^p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b/8/xaAoTttAwTA6xThIO8UkKCXeNMiuODaluLjCoMgkSDeu4P9/cwA)

Prints 1 if the number at the top of the stack is a fibonacci number, 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 87 bytes

```
read z;f=0;g=1;h=1
for((;;)){
h=$(($f+$g))
if [ $z == $f ];then echo 1;fi  
f=$g;g=$h
}
```

Attention endless loop, no break - stop the code after some seconds manually

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcy7DYAwDAXA3lO8wkUiGiJKy5MgCj5xTAMSUIGYPXAD3DSeXuuRxwW3mLZSNIlrItuPEERifMiVQ2BruMRIq6EH31AFGwa5PG/Is@9IYitAplz@hZ3eWlP3AQ)

Comment: You can shorten this to [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEMjzdZAJ93W0DrDNk073TrNNh3Iy9DUrObS0FAxtLVN09RUU0tNzshXMOSq/f//v6ExAA "Bash – Try It Online"), but I don't consider an endless loop to be a valid [output method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/17216). Halting upon printing the result only increases it to [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEMjzdZAJ93W0DrNRgVI2KYDORmamtVcGbYqadoq6Vy1XKnJGfkKKtEqhra2abH///83NAYA "Bash – Try It Online"). Note that in both of these, `$h` contains an unevaluated addition which is then automatically evaluated in the `for`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 36 bytes

```
\N:-1+N+0.
Y+N+X:-X<N,X+Y+N+Y;X=:=N.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcexCoAgEADQva9wVO4UG1osf@FmBadAQhANE/x8q@nx7lZzveQz0pyBjFyBQKvFfzgj3UHo4I/fnTWW1DSSBWD8jH3EWLjGTWskgYEwwGipx1w4CaHmCw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ĖÆF$Ƈ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWK45MO9zmpnKsfUlxUnIxVHDBIlNTCAsA)

##### Explanation

```python
ĖÆF$Ƈ  # Implicit input
Ė      # Push [0..input]
 ÆF    # For each n, get the nth Fibonacci number
       # (starting at 0->0, 1->1, 2->1, etc.)
   $Ƈ  # Is the input in this list?
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/), <s>58</s> 41 bytes

*-17 bytes thanks to [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)!*

```
f(n)=0^{mod((5nn+[4,0^n4-4])^{.5},1).min}
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xwdek7u2b5?nographpaper)

Checks if either \$5n^2+4\$ or \$5n^2-4\$ is a perfect square.

Comment: [42 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/c4otfdsais?nographpaper)

Comment: oh wait you can save a byte by going `0^n4-4` instead of `-4+0^n4` lol

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 66 bytes

```swift
func f(n:Int){var a=0,b=1,c=0;while n>a{c=a;a=b;b=c+b};print(n<a)}
```

---

[Try it out!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5941735488d3b319c4c1844c)
 - *NOTE: Prints `False` as truthy and `True` for falsy.*

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 37 bytes

```
{n->[-4,4].any{!((n*n*5+it)**0.5%1)}}
```

---

If `(5*(n**2)±4)**0.5` is ever an integer, the number is a fibbonacci number.

Answer (score 0):

## JS (ES6), 78 bytes

```
n=>{y=n?0:1;f=x=>x<3?1:f(x-1)+f(x-2);for(x=0;x<n+2;x++)f(x)==n?y=1:0;return y}
```

#### Ungolfed:

```
var f = n => {
    var y = n ? 0 : 1;
    f=x=>x<3?1:f(x-1)+f(x-2);//from this: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25142/70700
    for (var x = 0; x < n + 2; x++){
        if(f(x) == n){
            y = 1;
        }else{
            y = 0;
        }
    }
    return y;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

```c
a,b,c;f(n){for(a=0,b=1;n>(c=a);b=c)a+=b;n=(n==c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/dagMhEEavd59iEAJKbNBuyE@t7V2fojeuq4mUuGF0aSHk2bcmadJAvNCZwzDn0z5trB1Hw1tulaeRHXyP1GjBWy1VfKNWG6ZabZmZ6lZFTaMujTqOdvtFIwf3s3c2MzjU1R5DzJ4STycdA3R5wJhg0oGJHeStyRBKm2afkXCoqyqe75P0Vmh92fdObI9YCvJCDCSHoR8SOMQeCVP1sa53JkR61hYpBFVXJTjQoIUKr1KI8kynDIIH6mlgDK7pSh7CA1OwH3KixKAr2Rz4gCmDd9/wEdoe4rBrHabZyVadvipXzaKRci0aLh/YMxc3Jpt5GZJLcTf3xxbruzlxPf9sKeRcrJbN/BHdWa/oIj2Ovw)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 61 bytes

```
(def s(lazy-cat[0 1](map +(rest s)s)))#((set(take(inc %)s))%)
```

This actually constructs the Fibonacci sequence `s`, grabs enough elements from it and checks if the input is found. Returns `nil` for falsy and the input number for truthy.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 89 bytes

```
function f(n){s=Math.sqrt;c=Math.ceil;x=5*n**2;a=s(x-4);b=s(x+4);return c(a)==a||c(b)==b}
```

This uses the fact that all fibonacci numbers have the property that 5x^2+4 or 5x^2-4 must be square. It takes the square root of these numbers and checks if they equal their ceiling value.

## Javascript, 69 bytes (if it doesn't need to be a function)

```
s=Math.sqrt;c=Math.ceil;x=5*n**2;a=s(x-4);b=s(x+4);n=c(a)==a||c(b)==b
```

This one does the exact same thing, except instead of calling a function, you set `n` to the number to test, and `n` is set to true/false based on the result.

This is my first code golf entry, so let me know if there's anything to improve here. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 24 bytes

```
≈g<:|g=p+q┘p=q┘q=g]?g=a
```

### Explanation

```
≈g<:|   WHILE g (running fibonacci total) is less than input
g=p+q   Get the next fib by adding p (n-2, starts as 0) and q (n-1, starts as 1)
┘       (Syntactic linebreak)
p=q     increase n-2
┘       (Syntactic linebreak)
q=g     increase n-1
]       WEND
?g=a    PRINT -1 if g equals input (is a fib-number), or 0 if not.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>56 53</s> 50 bytes

- Thanks to @Fedone for 3 bytes: as a function

```python
def f(m):
 a=b=1
 while a<m:b,a=a,a+b
 print(a==m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcYxCsAgDADA3VdkTKiLuEnzmEgVBbVSLKWvT@lNN99VzuFVj5QhY6dgQDiyM/CU2hLI3kO0wmJliwbmVcdCYe6kGf/XMe@FRKTOfw)

Comment: [50 bytes as a function](https://tio.run/##FcYxCsAgDADA3VdkTKiLuEnzmEgVBbVSLKWvT@lNN99VzuFVj5QhY6dgQDiyM/CU2hLI3kO0wmJliwbmVcdCYe6kGf/XMe@FRKTOfw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 72 bytes

```
func f(i:Int,a:Int=0,b:Int=1)->Bool{return a<i ?f(i:i,a:b,b:a+b) :i==a}
```

Un-golfed:

```
func f(i:Int, a:Int=0, b:Int=1)->Bool{
    return a<i ? f(i: i, a: b, b: a+b) : i==a
}
```

I am recursively calling `f` until `a` is equal to or greater then `i`. Then, I check to see if `i` and `a` are equal.

You can try it [here](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59427dc90d43350685451e51)

Answer (score 0):

### [Python 3](https://github.com/python/cpython), 59 Bytes

```python
f=5*int(input())**2
print(not((f+4)**0.5%1and(f-4)**0.5%1))
```

Comment: You don't need the space between `and` and `(f-4)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3], 48 bytes

```python
m=0;k=1;exec("k,m=m,m+k\nif k==n:print(1)\n"*n)
```

If n is the input, we generate the first n Fibonacci numbers and check if our input is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 4 bytes

```
⌠rf╧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9Rz4KitEdTl///b8BlyGXEZcxlwmXKZcZlzmXBZcllCBQ05DI04jI0BgA)

### Explanation

We need to increment the input twice before creating the range because we know that \$F_{n+1} \geq n,\forall n \geq 0\$.

```
⌠      increment twice
 r     range(0, n)
  f    pop a, push fibonacci(a) (maps to the range)
   ╧   pop a, b, a.contains(b) (check if input is in list)
```

Answer (score 0):

## brev, 46 bytes

```
(c(fn(or(= x z)(and(< x z)(f y(+ x y)z))))0 1)
```