# Reverse Fibonacci

Tags: code-golf, fibonacci, subsequence

### Your task

You must write a program, to print a **reverse Fibonacci series**, given a number.

### Input

A **non-negative** integer ***N***.

### Output

You must output all the Fibonacci numbers from ***F<sub>k</sub>*** to ***F<sub>0</sub>***, where ***k*** is the smallest non-negative integer such that ***F<sub>k</sub>*** ≤ ***N*** ≤ ***F<sub>k+1</sub>***.

### Example

```
IN: 5

OUT: 5 3 2 1 1 0
```

***If input isn't a Fibonacci number, the series should begin from the closest Fibonacci number less than the input.***

```
IN:  15

OUT: 13 8 5 3 2 1 1 0
```

***If input is 1, the series should be.***

```
IN:  1

OUT: 1 0
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte count wins.

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=136123,OVERRIDE_USER=60869;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: So normal Fibonacci and then reversing the output?

Comment: Yeah, I mean to 0, thanks!

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85567/42963).

Comment: @AdmBorkBork isn't that the 'inverse Fibonacci function' and not 'return the fibonacci sequence, reversed'?

Comment: I'd say it's actually the reversed inverse Fibonacci function. (Sort of ...)

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I was about to ask that, but specifically - "You must output all the Fibonacci numbers from N to 0." implies we are *never* contracted to output both 1s

Comment: I've updated your question with a more formal definition. Feel free to rollback anything you'd dislike.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Sorry for the multiple edits. I think it's correct now.

Comment: @Arnauld you have changed the spec to invalidate multiple answers I believe. I'd suggest allowing `...1,0` or `...1,1,0` for *any* `n>0`, as that was what was implied by the original spec (see my comment above).

Comment: @JonathanAllan I've updated the spec to reflect the rule _"If input is 1, the series should be 1 0"_ (which was prior to my edit). But I tend to agree with you: both 1,1,0 and 1,0 should probably be allowed.

Comment: @Arnauld apologies for my mistaken attribution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 5 bytes

```
f₁>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3/P@1RU6Pdh7lTp32YO2H1//@mXAA)

## Explanation

```
f            infinite list of fibonacci numbers
 ₁>          get input and increment it
            first b elements of a
            reverse the list
```

I feel like this could be golfed more. `₁>` feels a bit inefficient...

Comment: It is output fibonacci numbers up to **n**, not output the first **n** numbers.

Comment: @Emigna of course, my mistake. will revise or delete in a few hours

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 52 bytes

```
p=0:scanl(+)1p
f 1=[1,0]
f n=reverse$takeWhile(<=n)p
```

Second line is necessary for the `n = 1` edge-case. I wasn't able to get around it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>62</s> 59 bytes

```python
n,l,a,b=input(),[],0,1
while a<=n:l=[a]+l;a,b=b,a+b
print l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P08nRydRJ8k2M6@gtERDUyc6VsdAx5CrPCMzJ1Uh0cY2zyrHNjoxVjvHGqQqSSdRO4mroCgzr0Qh5/9/Q1MA)

Comment: [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI08nxzY6VifR1kAnydZQ04pLoTwjMydVIdHGNs8KKJUYq51jnQiUS9JJ1E7iUigoyswrUcj5D6HVTa3UudI0TDW5oHxDiIChqeZ/AA)

Comment: [59 bytes for `input()-print` format](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P08nRydRJ8k2M6@gtERDUyc6VsdAx5CrPCMzJ1Uh0cY2zyrHNjoxVjvHGqQqSSdRO4mroCgzr0Qh5/9/Q1MA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: This gives `[1, 1, 0]` for input 1, the correct output is `[1, 0]`.

Comment: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##PcoxDoAgDADA3VcwUukgJi7GvoQwlAjRRAtBF1@PTm43XHnuLcvYWqKDz7CyEmQaMJCdtbM4@F4LkYVcVdKCAdkEMI497EnxQqLicUXnW6m73N@xE3S/oWsv) but I feel like this definitely isn't the best way to do this...  Note: this properly handles 1 -> `[1, 0]` and not `[1, 1, 0]`.

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##TcqxCoAgEIDhvadwzLpBg5bonkQcTlIS7Ixq6enNqdp@Pv79vtbMQykBE21uIcFAqMChnowGZbuWEbXMhwgtgwPqnewN2RgEzcjCp9MbW/Yj8lUXPcrm7S/VTyuXBw) cause I was stupid and had extra parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>9</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḤḶÆḞṚ>Ðḟ
```

A monadic link taking a number and returning the list of numbers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//4bik4bi2w4bhuJ7huZo@w5DhuJ////81)**

Note: I am assuming 1s are not both required, if they are the previous 9 byter works: `+2ḶµÆḞṚfṖ`

#### How?

```
ḤḶÆḞṚ>Ðḟ - Link: number, n
Ḥ        - double n (this is to cater for inputs less than 6)
 Ḷ       - lowered range of that -> [0,1,2,...,2*n-1]
  ÆḞ     - nth Fibonacci number for €ach -> [0,1,1,...,fib(2*n-1)]
    Ṛ    - reverse that
      Ðḟ - filter discard if:
     >   -   greater than n?
```

...the reason this only outputs `[1,0]` for an input of `1` is that the unfiltered list does not contain `fib(2)`, the second `1`.

The 9 byter works by adding two, `+2`, to form the lowered range `[0,1,2,...,n,(n+1)]` rather than doubling and then filter keeping, `f`, any results which are in a popped, `Ṗ`, version of that same list, `[0,1,2,...,n]` (the value accessed by making a monadic chain, `µ`).

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
Reverse@Select[Array[Fibonacci,t=1+#,0],#<t&]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/KLUstag41SE4NSc1uSTasagosTLaLTMpPy8xOTlTp8TWUFtZxyBWR9mmRC1W7X9AUWZeiYJDmoKDIRcS2/Q/AA)

thanx to @JungHwan Min for -16 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 28 bytes

```
{x/⍨⍵≥x←⌽{1∧+∘÷/0,⍵/1}¨⍳2×⍵}
```

Requires `⎕IO←0`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVE//R20TDLjSgGR1hf6j3hWPerc@6lxaAeQ/6tlbbfioY7n2o44Zh7frG@gApfQNaw8BlWw2OjwdyKsFGtG7qhrI0lFQf9Q2SV1HIQ0kfGiFoTZIkQEA)

**How?**

`{1∧+∘÷/0,⍵/1}` - apply fibonacci

`¨⍳2×⍵` - to the range `0` .. `2n`

`x←⌽` - reverse and assign to `x`

`x/⍨` - filter x with

`⍵≥x` - the function `x <= n`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

*Note: invalidated by recent specification change* (`1` -> `(1, 1, 0)`)

```python
n=input()
r=1,0
while r[0]<=n:r=(r[0]+r[1],)+r
print r[1:]
```

A full program accepting from stdin and printing (a tuple representation of) the numbers in the reversed order.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDk6vI1lDHgKs8IzMnVaEo2iDWxjbPqshWA8TULoo2jNXR1C7iKijKzCsBShtaxf7/b2gEAA)** or see a [test suite](https://tio.run/##JY5BDsIgEADP3VdwA1IOhSORlzQcsEVLUheyxaivx6K3SSaTTPnULaNpS14jc4xz3tAlLM8qJJDTaoLXlvbIaJ78xaElJzqONGuv5EhQKGE9tba@nTn8YreHx3UNtsajwi0T68ASMgp4j8IYaWH4l90oGOI7LqJfyPYF)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 40 bytes

```perl6
{[R,] 0,1,*+*...^{2>$_??$^a==1!!$^b>$_}}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##ZZDBbsIwEETv/oqFRpUdFguDQAjLwAf0VPVWNVWabKWIFCzioEZRvj21SeHCcWeeZmfX0rlc9XVFcFnJTLOfBp6zU05g@vb9FT9ghgrjSSylTNr5Nvrc7aIkNUaNRlHy5eeu658eyDgYIWvvqHJggDOAJZgt8CUucO5JhTOBXlWDrBa4xgdvsK6T0Cy0fPN5mtkyPcLkGq7Z9@n8v2fqadgcqOFRcbS1EwibS1rWxPf0aylzlAsQ0ProoprmRLZsIFx74@VLUTmEO40wHpxQ5K5K65/GxVizrv8D)

### Explanation:

- `{…}` create a bare block lambda with implicit parameter `$_`
- `[R,] LIST` is a Left fold using the reverse meta-op `R` combined with the comma op `,`.
  (shorter than `reverse`)
- `0, 1, *+* ...^ Callable` produces a Fibonacci sequence that stops on the value before **`Callable`** returns a `True` value.

The remaining code is a bit complicated as it has to return `True` if the original input is `1` and the second to latest value is `1`. This is so that the full lambda returns `(1,0)` instead of `(1,1,0)`.

```perl6
{ # bare block lambda with two placeholder params ｢$a｣ and ｢$b｣

    2 > $_    # is the original input smaller than 2

  ??          # if it is
    $^a == 1  # check if the second to latest value is 1

  !!          # otherwise
    $^b > $_  # check if the latest value is bigger than the original input
}
```

---

If the code was allowed to return `(1,1,0)` when given the value `1`, it can be dramatically shorter at 22 bytes:

```perl6
{[R,] 0,1,*+*...^*>$_}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##ZZDBCsIwEETv@YpBRJK6BqsoYqj4AZ7Em6hIu0KxarCpWMRvr6lVLx535jGzu5av2bgqcsZtrGMjTiU68SVhRNVjvaQN@hRS0A201ttg1t49K0/MHecOEaQARohmkCMa0sCTIfUVeTVs5HBIE/rzGuszKyPq9pVPNMJm@zO673gjDpfrp6nneUyPXMp2eraFU4TpbZ8VLOd8txw7ThQUHj48zXsJs81K1Fd8eb1Ic0f40YRW49Sr/FRt/TOkahnxrF4)

In this case `* > $_` creates a *WhateverCode* lambda that in this use-case will return `True` if the generated value is greater than the original input.

Everything else is the same as above.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>52</s> 41 bytes

```
{1,0}//.{a_,b_,c___}/;a+b<#:>{a+b,a,b,c}&

Fibonacci@Range[Floor[Log[GoldenRatio,1+√5#]],0,-1]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
ÎÅF)˜RIi¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cN/hVjfN03OCPDMPLfv/39AUAA)

If `[1, 1, 0]` is valid output for **1** this would be `ÎÅF)˜R` at 6 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>20</s> <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 13 bytes

Thanks a lot @Zgarb for telling me about `İf` which is a built-in for Fibonacci numbers, this saved me `4` bytes:

```
§↓=1ȯ↔`↑:0İf≤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9odXNr///Cp@KGkz0xyK/ihpRg4oaROjDEsGbiiaT///8yMA)

#### Ungolfed/Explanation

```
               -- implicit input N
          İf   -- get all Fibonacci numbers,
        :0     -- prepend 0,
      `↑    ≤  -- take as as long as the number is ≤ N,
    ȯ↔         -- reverse and
§ =1           -- if input == 1:
 ↓             --   drop 1 element else no element
```

---

### Old answer without built-in (17 bytes)

The old answer is quite similar to [shooqie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136137/48198)'s Haskell answer:

```
§↓=1ȯ↔`↑ȯƒo:0G+1≤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9odXNr///Cp@KGkz0xyK/ihpRg4oaRyK/Gkm86MEcrMeKJpP///zIw)

#### Ungolfed/Explanation

A really short way to compute Fibonacci numbers in Haskell is to define a recursive function like this (also see the Haskell answer):

```
fibos = 0 : scanl (+) 1 fibos
```

Essentially that code computes the [fixpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) of the function `\f -> 0 : scanl (+) 1 f`, so you can rewrite `fibos` in an anonymous way like this:

```
fix (\f -> 0 : scanl (+) 1 f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/nysts0IhTcEWiDXATE0urtzEzDygSEFRZl6JgooCSFgjJk1B107BQMFKoTg5MS9HQUNbU8EQqPr/fwA)

This corresponds to the [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) code `(ƒo:0G+1)`, here's the remaining code annotated:

```
                   -- implicit input N
        ȯƒo:0G+1   -- generate Fibonacci numbers (ȯ is to avoid brackets),
      `↑        ≤  -- take as as long as the number is ≤ N,
    ȯ↔             -- reverse and
§ =1               -- if input == 1:
 ↓                 --   drop 1 element else no element
```

Comment: You can use the built-in `İf` for the list of Fibonacci numbers (I realized that this is not yet documented anywhere).

Comment: The part `´o↓=3` doesn't work like you describe. It's interpreted as `argdup (.) . dropWhile . (==) $ 3`, which drops leading `3`s twice. [Try it.](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9odXNr///CtG/ihpM9M@KGlGDihpHIr8aSbzowRysx4omk////Mw)

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr///Cp@KGkz0xyK/ihpRg4oaROjDEsGbiiaT///8x) seems to work for 13 bytes.

Comment: No problem. In general, you should use `Ṡab` instead of `´oab` when the intended meaning is `\x -> a (b x) x`. It's shorter and has fewer possible types.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 70 bytes

```cs
n=>{var t="0";for(int a=0,b=1,c;b<=n;c=a,a=b,b+=c)t=b+" "+t;return t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcuxCsIwEIDhvU9xdGpplBYRh/S6CE46iINzEmMJ1Ask14KUPnusu87f/5u4MT7YNEZHPdzeke1LZmZQMcJ1ziIrdgYm7x5wUY6Kcs5OI5nWEQuIHNargx4TYTdPKgBjXufy6UOxFqCwFhobYaRukaRBJRRqoSs0JaOucsgrlsHyGAhYLklmR0/RD3Z7D47t2ZEt@mJXlr/h8A@a/VeWJX0A)

Input is an integer into the Lambda. Output is a space-delimited string of the fibonacci sequence in reverse.

Comment: Outputs `1 1 0` for `1` it should be `1 0`

Comment: I must have missed that in the specc. I would think that N=0 would give 1 0. There are other solutions here that output 1 1 0 as well for N=1.

Anyway, I will work on making it conform with the specc.

Comment: You did not misread the spec, it got changed. I have commented about it.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 42 bytes

```js
f=(n,a=0,b=1)=>b>n|a>=n?a:f(n,b,a+b)+" "+a
```

Alternative, if `f(1)` = `1 1 0`

```
f=(n,a=0,b=1)=>b>n?a:f(n,b,a+b)+" "+a
```

Example code snippet:

```js
f=(n,a=0,b=1)=>b>n|a>=n?a:f(n,b,a+b)+" "+a

console.log(f(5))
console.log(f(15))
console.log(f(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 58 bytes

```
{|k|a=0;b=1{{[a];b=a+b;a=b-a}while[a<k,b<=k];[a]}|reverse}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYoxDsIwEARr3ytOaQkSKWhI/ADeEKLoTC4QBezItqCw/XZjiQJWW6x2xpqJcgAsmU/ykkNcI8lDq2QTQk9DGbRTLUm1p/S@Lw/uqVtr1cl1aAtP0fKLreOUE8CTFo0BxEblOWvPN7Y4YsTZWPTs/HglxzgZEGKzi/ZYSYlV/WMFzH9mxK82gpiMZkj5CE3pBw)